# how i can use an output as input?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

i try to use the output from component "event-settings" as input by the component "events-list" how i can solve this problem ?

```
<ion-content padding>
    <button ion-button type="button" class="showFilterBtn" (click)="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed"
            [attr.aria-expanded]="!isCollapsed" >
      Show Filter
    </button>

    <event-settings [eventName]="false" [accompaniment]="false" [hidden]="isCollapsed" (searchedEvents)="getSearchedEvents($event)"></event-settings>
    <events-list *ngIf="this.events!= 'undefined'" [events]="this.events"></events-list>
</ion-content>
```

My Output is an Eventemitter called seachEvents

```
public searchEvents(){

    let startdatetime= this.start.split("T");
    let startdate = startdatetime[0].split("Z")[0];
    let starttime = startdatetime[1].split("Z")[0];

    let enddatetime = this.end.split("T");
    let enddate = enddatetime[0].split("Z")[0];
    let endtime = enddatetime[1].split("Z")[0];

    this.EventService.getEventsByFilter(this.userId,this.age,startdate,enddate,this.musicDirection,
        this.maxPerson,this.country,this.federaleState,this.city)
        .forEach((events) => {
            this.searchedEvents.emit(events);
        });
}
```

and this.events (observable) is  data from my ouput

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First remove "this" in front of the input variable it can fix it.

If not there is an easiest solution than RxJs. First I guess your function for setting getSearchEvents change the event variable ? (Add your code if possible)

So When you emit the event you change the variable event and let your event list know every time about it using a setter :

```
event = new Event();
@Input() set eventChange(event) {
    this.event = event;
}
```

In your HTML replace [event] with [eventChange] and you are done ;)

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer! but i cant write new Event(); because Event needs parameters

Comment: It was a sample class name, you can write event: any = null;

Comment: Please explain what error you have because it not working is too general

Comment: i get the events in console.log but the rendering in events-list not working

Comment: <ion-list>
  <button ion-item *ngFor="let event of events | async" (click)="showEvent(event)">
    <ion-title>{{event.name}}</ion-title>
    <div class="event-details">
    <p>Kind of Homeparty: {{event.art}}</p>
    <p>Start {{event.startdate}} at {{event.starttime}}</p>
    <p>End {{event.enddate}} at {{event.endtime}}</p>
    <p>Music Direction: {{event.musicDirection}}</p>
      <p>City: {{event.city}}</p>
    </div>
  </button>
</ion-list>

Comment: ok the name was wrong but now i get "this _subscribe is not a function

Comment: There is no subscribe using event emitter remove that subscribe it only works with observable and behavior subject

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to use a rxjs observable or subject. The other option is to use a service and is detailed in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/35878524/3211852