# How to pass dynamic parameters through components on Angular?

Tags: angular, components

So the problem I have is that I want to have a parameter being passed through two components in my Angular app, and when I change its value on the first component, the value also gets changed on the second one.

For the example here, I have a game component in which I can modify two numeral values (row and column), and a grid component (which is called in the game component) that would show an HTML table with the number of rows and columns from the game component which can be changed dynamically.

Here is `game.component.html`

```
<header>
    <h1>
        Test App
    </h1>
</header>

<div>
    Number of rows: {{row}}
    <button (click)="addRow()" >+</button>
    <button (click)="removeRow()" >-</button>
</div>

<div>
    Number of columns: {{column}}
    <button (click)="addColumn()" >+</button>
    <button (click)="removeColumn()" >-</button>
</div>

<grid [row]="row" [column]="column" >
</grid>
```

Here is `game.component.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'game',
  templateUrl: './game.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./game.component.css']
})
export class GameComponent implements OnInit {

  @Output() rowChange = new EventEmitter<number>();
  @Output() columnChange = new EventEmitter<number>();

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  row = 5;

  column = 5;

  addRow(){
    this.changeRow(1);
  }

  removeRow(){
    this.changeRow(-1);
  }

  changeRow(delta: number){
    this.row = Math.max(0, this.row + delta);
    this.rowChange.emit(this.row);
  }

  addColumn(){
    this.changeColumn(1);
  }

  removeColumn(){
    this.changeColumn(-1);
  }

  changeColumn(delta: number){
    this.column = Math.max(0, this.column + delta);
    this.columnChange.emit(this.column);
  }

}
```

Here is `grid.component.html`

```
<table>
    <tr *ngFor="let r of row">
        <td *ngFor="let c of column">
            test
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And `grid.component.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'grid',
  templateUrl: './grid.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./grid.component.css']
})
export class GridComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() row: number;
  @Input() column: number;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

Comment: Maybe the way you are looking for is using a Service. Would that be possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to share data/change between components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35878160/how-to-share-data-change-between-components)