# How to access data from sibling state?

Tags: angular

I have following setup:

```
--Users
  --User Table Component
  --User Filtering State
```

When I go to `Users`, I can see component `User Table Component`. I am trying to access some object, that is in this component, from the state of `User Filtering State`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## approach 1: Template variables

One way is to use [template variables](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#local-vars). `<some-component #someName>` creates a `someName` variable with a reference to the `SomeComponent` component and this variable can be refered to in bindings:

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'sibling1',
  template: `sibling1`)}
class Sibling1 {
  @Input() sib1Input;
  sib1Property:string = 'somevalue';
}
```

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'sibling2',
  template: `sibling2`)}
class Sibling1 {
  @Input() sib2Input;
  sib2Property:string = 'somevalue';
}
```

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'parent',
  directives: [Sibling1, Sibling2],
  template: `
<sibling1 #sib1 [sib1Input]="sib2.sib2Property"></sibling1>
<sibling2 #sib2 [sib2Input]="sib1.sib1Property"></sibling2>`)}
class Parent {
}
```

## approach 2: Shared service

another way is to use shared services like demonstrated in
- [Delegation: EventEmitter or Observable in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34376854/delegation-eventemitter-or-observable-in-angular2/35568924)

Below a simplified version (without observables). For how to use observables to get notified about changes, see the linked answer.

```ts
@Injectable() 
class SharedService {
  someValue:string;
}
```

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'sibling1',
  template: `sibling1`)}
class Sibling1 {
  constructor(private sharedService:SharedServcie) {}

  clickHandler() {
    sharedService.someValue = 1;
  }
}
```

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'sibling2',
  template: `sibling2
    <div>value from sibling1: {{sharedService.someValue}}</div>
`)}
class Sibling1 {
  constructor(private sharedService:SharedServcie) {}
}
```

Adding the `SharedService` to `providers` of `Parent` makes it shared among itself and it descendants (adding it to `bootstrap(AppComponent, [SharedService])` would make it globally shared with the whole application)

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'parent',
  directives: [Sibling1, Sibling2],
  providers: [SharedService], 
  template: `
<sibling1></sibling1>
<sibling2></sibling2>`)}
class Parent {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly access properties on such components. If you want to communicate between components, you could leverage a shared service.

It could contain both data and observables to subscribe on to be notified when data are updated.

Here is a sample:

- **Service**

  ```
  export class SharedService {
    list1Event: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

    getLists() {
      return this.http.get(url).map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(
          (data) => {
            this.list1Event.emit(data.list1);
          }
        );
    }
  }
  ```
- **Component**

  ```
  @Component({
    selector: 'my-component1',
    template: `
      <ul>
       <li *ngFor="#item of list">{{item.name}}</li>
      </ul>
    `
  })
  export class MyComponent1 {
    constructor(private service:ListService) {
      this.service.list1Event.subscribe.(data => {
        this.list = data;
      });
    }
  }
  ```
- **bootstrap**

  ```
  bootstrap(AppComponent, [ SharedService ]);
  ```

See this question for more details:

- [Delegation: EventEmitter or Observable in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34376854/delegation-eventemitter-or-observable-in-angular2/35568924#35568924)
- [Delegation: EventEmitter or Observable in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34376854/delegation-eventemitter-or-observable-in-angular2/34402436#34402436)
- [Is possible to have two template for single call service in AngularJS 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35761450/is-possible-to-have-two-template-for-single-call-service-in-angularjs-2/35764734#35764734)