# Nested Angular2 ngFor Directives for Firebase Lists

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I want to bind the results of a Firebase query to my template using `ngFor` in Angular 2. This is easily achieved below.

component:

```
export class FeaturedThreadsComponent { 
    threads: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
    qualitySubject: Subject<any>;

    constructor(af: AngularFire) {
        this.qualitySubject = new Subject();
        this.threads = af.database.list('/threads', {
            query: {
                orderByChild: 'quality',
                endAt: 5
            }
        });
    }
}
```

template:

```
<div *ngFor="let thread of threads | async">
    {{thread.title}}
</div>
```

But if I want to use another `ngFor` directive nested within the template to list a child object's keys...

```
<div *ngFor="let thread of threads | async">
    {{thread.title}}
    <div *ngFor="let participant of thread.participants">
        {{participant.$key}}}
    </div>
</div>
```

I get the console error, `Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.`

In my database structure, `participants` is a child of `thread`, which is a child of `threads` where `thread` is a dynamic key. So I can't use a direct path to `participants`.

This pattern of nesting `ngFor` directives worked fine in a service that simply iterated over a local file. Why it isn't working here seems a bit fuzzy to me.

Comment: I don't think so. If I use the actual key `{{participant.adam}}` I get the same console error. I suspect this is related to attempting to iterate over the object  `participants` that Angular 2 doesn't recognize as an array.

Comment: `thread.participants` will be an object and will be non-iterable with `ngFor`. That's the core problem and the referenced question's accepted answer should help you with that.

Comment: Is it that `threads: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;` stores `threads` as an array that it's iterable? That would seem to make sense. That would mean this question is more of a usage question that is specific to Firebase/Angularfire2 it seems. Because I need a way to get `participants` into an array of observables when it is a child of a dynamic key that can't be exposed in a direct path.

Comment: Yep, AngularFire2 `list` observables emit array values, so they are fine with `ngFor`, but any list-ish properties in them will be represented as objects (i.e. keys and values) and `ngFor` cannot be used with those directly. The referenced answer is your solution. (Which is why this is a dupe. Which is not a sin; it's just the way these things are handled.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those of you who follow this thread to the one it is flagged as a duplicate of, resist creating a pipe like the accepted answer suggests. [The best answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39896058/6024090) avoids the [performance issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35534959/access-key-and-value-of-object-using-ngfor/39896058#comment66192984_35536052) of the accepted answer and is much simpler.