# Nested query using AngularFire2/Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I am using **Angular2** along with **Firebase**?After searching a lot I got to know that there is no way to do nested query on firebase data,so I need to restructure my database.Could anyone tell me what is the other way to structure my data with some example?

Below is the data structure on firebase

[image]

Comment: Yes, you can do nested queries. No, we cannot tell you if there's a better structure since we have no idea what you or your app is trying to do. Help us to help you by providing accurate, complete and brief information.

Comment: As @Jay said, it is possible to "nest" or "join" Firebase queries. One example of such can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41769360/joining-firebase-queries-in-angularfire2).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a similar structure.I wanted to match a reference key of one collection to an array of reference keys in another collection. If your need is similar to mine. Here is a solution:

This is what I did :

```js
this.af.database.list('books').subscribe(snapshot=>{
        snapshot.forEach(book=>{
          if(book.authors && book.authors.indexOf(auth.uid)!=-1)
          {
            this.books.push(book);
          }
        })
       
        
      })
```

Hope it helps. All the best.

Comment: Thank you Ankita.As I am a newbie this is helpful for me.