# How to iterate over objects using <template>

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template

Hi I am trying to iterate over the provided object and want to print the keys in the DOM

```
obj = {
    "approved" : ["1231312","alkjdkasjld"],
    "rejected" : ["1231312","alkjdkasjld"]
  }
```

and i am iterating like below to print approved and rejected

```
<template ngFor let-key [ngForOf]="obj">
  {{key}} 
  </template>
```

but its not working, please help 
Plunker 
https://plnkr.co/edit/X9QN54A36qWqLJKYmARE?p=preview

Comment: Possible duplicate of [access key and value of object using \*ngFor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35534959/access-key-and-value-of-object-using-ngfor)

Comment: Thanks a lot it helped !!