# How do I target a object key in *ngFor loop with Angular2

Tags: angular

In Angular 2 latest RC context I try to build a view with several tabs.
Data come from an API where I need to make calls in two steps to retrieve targeted data.

- Each tabs contains accordion groups and relate to `categories`
- Each accordion groups contains bullet list and relate to
  `categories[i].subtopics`

This part works perfectly well.

Things become more tricky when I try to implement the `<li>`tag with data coming from a second array `subTopics`.
I try several combinations of `*ngFor="let services of subTopics` without success.
What are y options to display the way I want (see comment in HTML template)

#### My component HTML

```
<tabset>
<tab heading="{{category.name}}" *ngFor="let category of categories | orderBy" >
    <h2>Content</h2>
    <accordion>
        <accordion-group  heading="{{subtopic.name}}" *ngFor="let subtopic of category.subtopics | orderBy">
            <li>
<!-- Here is where I want to display value for each services.name key related to my subtopic. -->
           </li>
        </accordion-group>
    </accordion>
</tab>
```

#### My `categories` JSON

My `categories` array structure looks like this.
After retrieving this object I iterate over each `categories[index].subtopics`in order to generate my `subTopics` array.

```
[{
    "code": "FIRST_CATEGORY",
    "name": "First Categories", //Tab heading
    "subtopics": [{
        "code": "CODE1",
        "name": "Name for Code 1" //Accordion group heading
    }, {
        "code": "CODE2",
        "name": "Name For Code 2" //Accordion group heading
    }]
},{
    "code": "SECOND_CATEGORY",
    "name": "Second Categories", //Tab heading
    "subtopics": [{
        "code": "CODE3",
        "name": "Name for Code 3" //Accordion group heading
    }, {
        "code": "CODE4",
        "name": "Name for Code 4" //Accordion group heading
    }]
}]
```

#### My `subTopics` JSON

My `subTopics` array structure looks like this. I simplify it a lot, as there is many key/value per `services`.

```
[{
    "subtopic": "CODE1",
    "services": [{
        "code": "755",
        "name": "The Name of My Code 755" //my <li> Tag
    }, {
        "code": "199",
        "name": "The Name of My Code 199" //my <li> Tag
    }]
}, {
    "subtopic": "CODE2",
    "services": [{
        "code": "761",
        "name": "The Name of My Code 761" //my <li> Tag
    }, {
        "code": "356",
        "name": "The Name of My Code 356" //my <li> Tag
    }]
}]
```

This array is build using this function where `code` and `index` coming from my `categories`array iteration.

```
getSubServicePerTopic(code, index){
    this._dxdService.getSubTopics(code, this.regionId)
    .subscribe(subTopics => {
        this.subTopics[index] = subTopics;
    });
}
```

Comment: where and which element you want to target of supTopics?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [access key and value of object using \*ngFor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35534959/access-key-and-value-of-object-using-ngfor)

Comment: where : in my <li> tag which: a key of my topic, like topic.name

Comment: thanks @ChristopherMoore I already review that topic. Could it be that I failed to build a proper Pipe()?

Comment: `ngFor` works with `Array`. It seems you are using `subTopics[0]` and as you have mentioned that `subTopics` contains an array of object, `subTopics[0]` should contain an object which will not work with `ngFor`. So use `subTopics` instead.

Comment: @Benoit Impossible to say without looking at more of your code :) If you don't want to use a pipe, create a function getKeyArray() and call that instead

Comment: I'll update my post with more code.

Comment: Please show structure of `categories` and `subTopics`. :) Maybe show your `Pipe` too.

Comment: @mxii I've update my post with complete overview of my HTML templates and JSON structure for the 2 arrays involved. Hope it makes more sens. Any input will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite sure whats your exact problem, but here's a starting point to discuss. :)

Changed your component's (tabset, tab, ..) to div's:

```html
<div class="tabset">
  <div class="tab" *ngFor="let category of categories" >
      <h2>{{category.name}}</h2>

      <div class="accordion">
          <div class="accordion-group" *ngFor="let subtopic of category.subtopics">
            <h3>{{ subtopic.name }} </h3>
            <ul>
              <li *ngFor="let service of getServices(subtopic)">
                <!-- Here is where I want to display value for each services.name key related to my subtopic. -->
                {{ service.code }} : {{ service.name }}
             </li>
           </ul>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
getServices(subtopic) {
   let s = this.subtopics.find(st => st.subtopic == subtopic.code);
   return s ? s.services : [];
}
```

live demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/HfQTYONXB67DvkQnv4KL?p=preview

Comment: Many thanks @mxii. It put me on the right path but not yet fixed. In live scenario my `subtopics`is populated after API call when `categories`in done. So with you example s.services always return `undefined`.

Comment: What is the option to make the getService call waiting for `subtopics` being populated. I try with `.then()`but it's not an allowed type. At least I learn that I can call a function in *ngFor. Angular is new for me

Comment: Tweaking your function as it `getServices(subtopic) {

   if(typeof this.subtopics[subtopic.code] !== "undefined"){
    return this.subtopics[subtopic.code].services;
   }
  }` returns what I expect, but it take some seconds I don't really understand Might be a better way?

Comment: What do you mean with `takes some seconds`?

Comment: When my App loads, the `subtopics` Array is empty as it is populated after `categories` are ready with several API calls based on `categories.subtopics`. Maybe there is a better way to postpone loading of the app when all data are retrieved? Currently the complete sequence takes around 5 seconds

Answer (score 0):

Tweaking your function as it

```
getServices(subtopic) {
    if(typeof this.subtopics[subtopic.code] !== "undefined"){
        return this.subtopics[subtopic.code].services;
            }
        }
```

returns what I expect, but it take some seconds I don't really understand Might be a better way?