# ionic 2 Populate Select Options from json

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm trying to dynamically populate a `ion-select` dropdown with a json object.

My html component looks like this:

```
<ion-item [hidden]="editOptions.isEditing">
  <ion-note stacked color="primary">{{label}}</ion-note>
  <ion-note class="inline-edit"> {{value}}&nbsp;</ion-note>
</ion-item>
<ion-item [hidden]="!editOptions.isEditing">
  <ion-label stacked color="primary">{{label}}</ion-label>

  <ion-select [(ngModel)]="value" [selectOptions]="additionalData" [required]="required" [name]="value">
    <!--<ion-option>None</ion-option>-->
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

and In my calling code i try to populate the select options but they have no example in there documentation

```
additionalData = {
  title: 'Pizza Toppings',
  subTitle: 'Select your toppings',
  mode: 'md'
};
```

How do I add my options to this select, without using an *ngFor in the html?
I would prefer to just pass them like so:

```
additionalData = {
  title: 'Pizza Toppings',
  subTitle: 'Select your toppings',
  mode: 'md'
  options: [{id:1, description:'Pepperoni'}]
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `[selectOptions]` are used to pass creation options ([docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/select/Select/#input-properties)). So you should make an iterable out of your json-object and use `*ngFor`.

**`*ngFor` example:**

A neat way of accessing object keys and values are by making use of `Object.keys` as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42813708/1783706) answer and shown below.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-page',
  templateURL: 'my-page.html
})

export class MyPage {
    // Make Object.keys available
    objectKeys = Object.keys;
    value = { option1: 'foo', option2: 'bar' };  

    constructor(){}
}
```

**HTML**

```
...  
    <ion-select [(ngModel)]="value" [required]="true" [name]="value">
        <ion-option *ngFor="let option of objectKeys(value)">
            {{ value[option] }}
        </ion-option>
    </ion-select>
...
```

This way theres no need to implement a custom pipe that basically does the same thing.

Comment: Yup.. just scroll up a bit to get to the example.. - and ironically just below where @jonny5 got his snippet about pizzas...

Comment: @JGFMK Its not ironic, because If you read the question I do not want to use an *ngFor I want to just pass the values to the select and have it auto populate

Comment: Also, if either of you were the ones to down vote please explain why

Comment: No I have not down voted the question. I really don't think there's another way to accomplish what you want. Not without putting in a lot of unnecessary effort. What is the reason behind the want to not use `*ngFor`?

Comment: yeah I was just checking I didn't think it was, but if it was I wanted to know why.  I guess since it cant be don then I have to do that What I really wanted was `<ion-select [selectOptions]='options' [selectValues]='values'></ion-select>`

Comment: Is there a way for the value that came from JSON api url?

Answer (score 1):

Have you perhaps tried...

```
<ion-select [selectOptions]="{
  title: 'Pizza Toppings',
  subTitle: 'Select your toppings',
  mode: 'md'
   }">
</ion-select>
```