# *ngFor Object in template Ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have object:

```ts
messages = [{
    'One' : [
        {'id' : 1},
        {'id' : 2},
    ],
    'Two' : [
        {'id' : 1},
        {'id' : 2},
    ]
}] ;
```

I have tried the below code but did't run please tell me where i am doing wrong.

```ts
<div *ngFor="let message of messages">
    <div>KEY</div>
    <div *ngFor="let value of message">VALUE</div>
</div>
```

In code i need show KEY and VALUE

**My Solution**

In component:

```ts
this.messages = data['messages'] ;
this.keys = Object.keys(data['messages']);
```

In view:

```ts
<div *ngFor="let key of keys">
    <div>{{key}}</div>
    <div *ngFor="let message of messages[key]">{{message['id']}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want to create a pipe you can expose `Object.keys` like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45256145/1783706) SO-answer.

**Your component:**

```
@Component({
    ...
})
export class YourComponent{
    objectKeys: any = Object.keys;
    messages: Array<any>;

    constructor(){}

    ...
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div *ngFor="let message of messages">
    <div *ngFor="let key of objectKeys(message)">
        <div>KEY: {{ key }}</div>
        <div *ngFor="let val of message[key]">{{ val.id }}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
KEY: One
1
2
KEY: Two
1
2
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a pipe like shown in [How to iterate [object object] using *ngFor in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41396435/how-to-iterate-object-object-using-ngfor-in-angular-2/41396558#41396558)

```ts
<div *ngFor="let message of messages">
    <div>KEY</div>
    <div *ngFor="let key of message | keys">{{message[key]}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: you're right, im sorry. i was probably blacking out