# Know which item is visible in ionic 2

Tags: ionic2

I have 100 items in a list like this. I would like to know which items of those 100 items is visible on screen, but seem ion-list doesn't provide that method. How can I achieve it?

```
<ion-list>
  <button ion-item *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="itemSelected(item)">
    {{ item }}
  </button>  
</ion-list>
```

Comment: Do these items have a fixed height? If so, you could do some maths based on the scroll position (and the header, and so on...), to calculate which items should be shown in that position...

Comment: unfortunately it's not fixed height.

Comment: Why would you need to know the visible items? Maybe if we know more about what your requirement is, we can find another way to do it

Answer (score 0):

You could try making item an object and then giving it an int index value in the backend typescript...

Try this

```
<tr *ngFor="#city of cities">
  <template [ngIf]="city.indexValue == '0'">
    <td>{{city.name}}</td>
  </template>
</tr>
```

In the typescript...

```
class MyComp {
   selectedCity: Object;
   cities: Object[] = [
      {name: "SF", indexValue: "0"},
      {name: "NYC", indexValue: "1"}
   ];
}
```

Comment: which method can I use to do it ?

Comment: look at this item how they're giving a key value pair, make the key the index and the value the 'value' of the item https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35534959/access-key-and-value-of-object-using-ngfor

Comment: then how to get the current key/value ?