# Angular 2 get key and value from json array with dynamic key

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to get key and value from json array with dynamic keys. Meaning, I don't know in advance what will be the keys.

This is an example to the json the function gets:

```
arr = [
       {key1: 'val1'},
       {key2: 'val2'},
       {key3: 'val3'}
      ];
```

It seems simple to me but I am unable to get the key and value for each item.

This is what I tried (based on [this pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35534959/access-key-and-value-of-object-using-ngfor/this%20pipe)):

```
for (let key of arr) {
   console.log ('key: ' +  key + ',  value: ' + arr[key]);
 }
```

But what I get in the log is the following:

```
key:[object Object], value: undefined
```

My expected behavior is to get the following:

```
key:key1, value:val1
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I get the keys and values?

Comment: for...of returns items (values) in array/object. for...in returns keys in array/object. so you need one more inner loop with for...in to get keys for each item.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In your example, you have an array of objects and each of these object has exactly one property.

```
for (let obj of arr) {
    console.log("object:", obj);
    for (let key in obj) {
        console.log("      key:", key, "value:", obj[key]);
    }
}
```

The following code from your posting

```
for (let key in arr) {
    console.log ('key: ' +  key + ',  value: ' + arr[key]);
}
```

... would work on a data structure like this:

```
let arr = {
    key1: 'val1',
    key2: 'val2',
    key3: 'val3'
};
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are more concerned to specify object like

```
var temp={'name':Dinesh,'age':18}
```

You may use following syntax.

```
console.log(Object.keys(temp)[0],Object.values(temp)[0]):
```

Specially zero index because object's both method keys and values return an array

Answer (score 3):

You need another for loop to access key and value,

```
for (let key of this.arr) {
 for(var i in key){
      console.log('key: ' +  i + ',  value: ' + key[i]);
 }
}
```

Check the **`console`**

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/3tCntGHQv7YfLpB1d2Cu?p=preview)**

Answer (score 0):

```
yourObject.forEach(function(value, index){
   // do your job
   console.log(value, index);
});
```

Comment: It's bad idea to name variable `Object`, and even for `arr.forEach` you'll get current index in `key`

Comment: Thank's dear @barbsan, i applied your advice

Answer (score 0):

You can try these

```
object = [
{
  "id": 1,
  "test": "test1",
  "name": ["abc", "pqr"]

},
{
  "id": 2,
  "test": "test2",
  "name": ["abc2", "pqr2"]

},
{
  "id": 3,
  "test": "test3",
  "name": ["abc3", "pqr3"]

},
{
  "id": 4,
  "test": "test4",
  "name": ["abc4", "pqr4"]

}]
```

and your js or typescript code be like:-

```
YourMethod() {
for (let item of this.object) {
  for (let i in item) {
    if (typeof (item[i]) === 'object') {
      item[i].forEach((e: any) => {
        console.log("runseprate", e)
      })
    }
  }
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   json = {payload.InsuredMobileNumber.type: "string"
payload.accidentTime.type: "string"
payload.causeOfLoss.type: "string"
payload.claimRegistrationDate.type: "string"
payload.emailAddress.type: "string"}


 var keyData = Object.keys(json);
          var valueData = Object.values(json)
          console.log("keyData = ", keyData)
          console.log("valueData = ", valueData)
```