# Angular2 Error trying to Diff

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have a form that I am trying to dynamically add controls to using reactiveForms.

Within my code, I am trying to populate a dropdown menu. I am using `formArray` since these are dynamic fields. The

**Data:**

`{
  "ruleName": "",
  "ruleDescription": "",
  "ruleOutcome": "",
  "addVariable": "2",
  "variables": [
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "Device Trust Score",
      "operator": [
        {
          "name": "Greater Than <",
          "id": 3
        },
        {
          "name": "Less Than >",
          "id": 4
        }
      ],
      "values": ""
    }
  ]
}`

**HTML:**

```
<tbody formArrayName="variables">
   <tr *ngFor="let variable of addRuleForm.get('variables').controls; let i=index" [formGroup]="variable">
   <td>{{ addRuleForm.controls.variables.controls[i].controls.name.value}}
      <input type="hidden" formControlName="id" value="addRuleForm.controls.variables.controls[i].controls.id.value" [attr.id]="'id'+i">
   </td>
   <td>
      <select class="form-control input-sm" formControlName="operator" [attr.id]="'operator'+i">
         <option value="">Select an Operator</option>
         <option *ngFor="let o of addRuleForm.controls.variables.controls[i].controls.operator.value" value="{{ o.id }}">{{ o.name }}</option>
      </select>
   </td>
   <td>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" (click)="removeVariable(v.id)"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
      </button>
   </td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

This select input gets rendered to the page just fine. I inspect the source and see that the value has also been set to the ID correctly.

However, as soon as I select an option from it, I get this error:

`Error: Error trying to diff '4'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed` referencing the ID of the item I selected.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That message may be telling you that you are trying to `*ngFor` something that it does not understand.

I assume this `addRuleForm.controls.variables.controls[i].controls.operator.value` might be 4? Did you mean to use the `value` property here?

If you want to iterate through a JSON object, you can use Object.keys. There are several examples here: [access key and value of object using *ngFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35534959/access-key-and-value-of-object-using-ngfor)

Comment: that line you pasted returns the following: `[ { "name": "In List", "id": 1 }, { "name": "Not In List", "id": 2 } ]`. That is what my `*ngFor` is trying to iterate

Comment: That's the problem then. *ngFor can only iterate arrays and iterables, not JSON objects.