# How to retrieve nested values after subscribing using angular and json data?

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I have created one getReports methods in which i am passing my web api get method and able to get the response in json format

```
Step1

    getReports() {
            return this._http.get(this.url)
                .map((response: Response) => response.json())
                .catch(this.handleError);  
        }
```

Step2

After this in my component constructor class i am injecting the complete service and   under ngOnInit i am subscribing using this.reports.

```
constructor(private _reportService: GetReports) {
    }
ngOnInit() {
       this._reportService.getReports().subscribe(reports => this.reports = reports);
}
```

so in console i am getting the Array with 127 records.My problem is how i can traverse the json data in component so that i will show my nested values

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzJMj.png)

for example while expanding above array i will get data in format of

```
0
     Key 1:" abdef",
     Key2 :[1,2,3 ]
     key 3:['test','test2']
1   
    Key 1:" check",
     Key2 :[1,2,3 ]
     key 3:['test3','test2']
 2 
     Key 1:" ghef",
     Key2 :[1,2,3 ]
     key 3:['test3','test2']
 ....
 ....
 ....
 127  
     Key 1:" check",
     Key2 :[1,2,3 ]
     key 3:['test4','test3']
```

I need to retrieve array value which is collection of the 127 elements like i mentioned above for 0th element I have Key 1 which having value"abdef" .. so first i need to find all the distinct values for Key 1 in 127 elements similarly based on key 1 i need to find all the distinct values which is under Key 3

I need to retrieve all the values belonging to Key 3 based on key1 and also duplicate  records will not come .

I went through the links like  [access key and value of object using *ngFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35534959/access-key-and-value-of-object-using-ngfor) but it is not fulfilling my requirement.

SO it will be great help if i get the links and responses on How to retrieve or read  the nested  json data in angular

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're looking for here. `this.reports[i]['key 3']` should give you the values for array index `i` (0-126). "I need to retrieve all the values belonging to Key 3 based on key1 and also duplicate records will not come ." needs clarification.

Comment: If you can show us what you are trying (even if it does not work), that would help us understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Sure DeborahK and Z. Bagley thanks for your response.Actually i missed the array image which i added now. I need to retrieve array value which is collection of the 127 elements like i mentioned above for 0th element I have Key1 which having value"abdef" .. so first i need to find all the distinct values for Key1 in 127 elements similarly based on key1 i need to find all the dstinct values which is under Key3

Comment: Can you give an example of input and output both?

Comment: Deshak9  input will be the array which i mentioned above and output will be                                    like  .check.....................[test2,test3,test4]

Answer (score 0):

Get all distinct keys

```
var distinctKyes = reports.map((a) => a.key1).filter((item, pos, arr) => arr.indexOf(item) === pos);
```

Fetch all key3 based on key1(value ="abc")

```
var result = []
myarr.forEach((item) => {
    if(item.key1 === "abc"){
        result = result.concat(item.key3);
    }
})

result = result.filter((item, pos) => result.indexOf(item) === pos);
```