# ngFor data structure

Tags: javascript, html, angular

There is somethign wrong with my data structure. I have resTest containing two object and keys such as pop,province, and address. I can think of couple options to do this but what would be easiest way to do this?

**html**

```
 var columnsA = ["Pop","Province","Address"];
var columnsB = ["Pop","Province","Address"];
var res = {};
res['A'] = this.columns;
res['B'] = this.columns;

    this.resTest = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(getRes));

    //this.resTest = {A: Array(24), B: Array(24)};

    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>RegionA</th>
          <th>RegionB</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of this.resTest">
          <td>{{item?.A}}</td>
          <td>{{item?.B}}</td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
     </table>
```

**error**

> ```
> ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables
> ```

I am expecting this data structure

> {A :{…}, B: {…}}

This is what I have

> {A: Array(24), B: Array(24)};

**table**
[image]

Comment: ngFor needs an array. You're assigning them to an object. Not entirely sure what you're trying to accomplish, but what ever is in your ngFor needs to be an array.

Comment: @jassok i am literally trying to list all those keys under each of header. My question is what is best way such that I am able to list them. If I have to change my data structure to array, how should I form from what I have?

Comment: Could you add what you're expecting / hoping the final table would look like?

Comment: @jassok Please see updated post, I tried convert to what I like to have but still can't get it working..

Comment: I mean the actual table that would be out put on the front end.

Comment: @jassok updated. If there are other ways such that I can literate through two object at the same time by using *ngFor, I don't really need to change my data structure.. so i am looking for easiest option to achieve this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [access key and value of object using \*ngFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35534959/access-key-and-value-of-object-using-ngfor)

Answer (score 0):

Since `ngFor` requires an Array, you JSON-parsed object needs to be refactored. This could be done via `Object.keys` and `Array.prototype.map` methods. Also, you should sort your array manually because `Object.keys` does not guarantee the order.

```
resTest = { A: [1, 2, 3], C: [3, 2, 1], B: [0, 0, 0] };

resTest = Object
  .keys(resTest)
  .sort((a, b) => {
    if (a < b) return -1;
    if (a > b) return 1;
    return 0;
  })
  .map(k => ({[k]: resTest[k]}));

// [{A: [1, 2, 3]}, {B: [0, 0, 0]}, {C: [3, 2, 1]}]
```

After that, you'll be able to pass `resTest` to the `ngFor`.

---

To convert your data into two-columns dataset, again, use `Array.prototype.map`:

```
resTest = { A: [1, 2, 3], B: [9, 8, 7] };

resTest = resTest['A']
  .map((r, index) => ({ 'A': resTest['A'][index], 'B': resTest['B'][index] }));

// [{A: 1, B: 9}, {A: 2, B: 8}, {A: 3, B: 7}]
```

In this case you need to be sure, that `A` and `B` properties have the same length.

Comment: This works perfectly fine but why does this append data via column? I expected to add items by rows

Comment: @ChoChang So what do you need from this point? I believe the error should go away and `item` is an object with one property which value is an array `{ X: [...] }`

Comment: @ChoChang I think, I've catched your request... see my updated answer

Comment: Sorry, Okay so using your example, I simply want to display as follow. I want 1,2,3 to be displayed under A column and 9,8,7 to be displayed under B column. And I want them to be appneded by each row, not by columns. (just like I described in question )

Comment: note that Grade corresponds to "A" and name to "B" in my example.

Comment: @ChoChang And I believe, I've just put the solution. Passing the last dataset to the `ngfor`, you'll get 3 rows appended to each other: (1, 9), (2, 8) and (3, 9), which exactly satisfies the requirement.

Comment: I get what you are saying now.. okay but i think it has to do something with my html? i don't get any errors at this point but no output to the table

Comment: @ChoChang It's defenitely another story. By the way I can't debug your code, especially not having it. You may create a demo on https://codepen.io or whatever and open a new question on SO, or give me the link to your demo.