# Add a row dynamically in table using Angular 7 and material

Tags: datasource, angular7

I want a `Notes` table, with two columns `DATE` and `Content`.

The rows should be arranged after the date. The last note added should be first. It should be an input field, in which you can write the note and automatically the date should be added and the entire entry should be added to the table when you hit the Add button.

I'm working with Angular 7 and Material, but I have no idea how to do this.

I'm not using bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the answer depends on how are you generating the table.

The first thing that comes to my mind is using `ngFor` - in such case you just add a new item to the underlying collection.

There are many examples out there, e.g. [Angular dynamic table using ngFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49491982/angular-dynamic-table-using-ngfor)