# Angular 8 dynamic table with JSON data

Tags: html, angular, angular8

I'm trying to create a table dynamically with **JSON** data, including the headers. 
I used this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49491982/angular-dynamic-table-using-ngfor) to get as far as I've gotten.

My problem is that the data in my table appears [completely messed up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aicmF.png). I know in my first for each loop I should only iterate through `dataMessageResults[0]`, but that gives me a syntax error.

My results.html:

```
<div class="play-container">

<h1>Child</h1>
    <table>
         <thead>
              <tr *ngFor="let item of dataMessageResults">           
                <th *ngFor="let item of dataMessageResults | keyvalue">{{item.key}}</th>
              </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
              <tr *ngFor="let item of dataMessageResults">           
                <td *ngFor="let list of item | keyvalue">{{item.value}}</td>
              </tr>
         </tbody>
    </table>
```

My results.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-message-results',
  templateUrl: './message-results.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./message-results.component.scss']
})

export class MessageResultsComponent {

  @Input() dataMessageResults: Object;

  constructor() { }

}
```

an example of the data. Angular seems to add a number for each JSON which is resulting in the numbers in the headers.

```
{
    "elemNb": "",
    "msgID": "",
    "year": "2019",
    "week": "42",
    "sysDatetime": "2019-10-16T11:57:34.748Z",
    "airline": "EJU",
},
{
    "elemNb": "",
    "msgID": "",
    "year": "2019",
    "week": "42",
    "sysDatetime": "2019-10-16T11:57:35.296Z",
    "airline": "DLH",
},
{
    "elemNb": "",
    "msgID": "",
    "year": "2019",
    "week": "42",
    "sysDatetime": "2019-10-16T11:59:48.599Z",
    "airline": "BAW",
    "tail": " ",
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: i'm assuming you created the custom pipe like that other post did and named it keyvalue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you want to iterate over an object? Your data should be an array! Then you can calculate your headers easily:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-message-results',
  templateUrl: './message-results.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./message-results.component.scss']
})

export class MessageResultsComponent {

  @Input() dataMessageResults: any[];

  constructor() { }

  getHeaders() {
    let headers: string[] = [];
    if(this.dataMessageResults) {
      this.dataMessageResults.forEach((value) => {
        Object.keys(value).forEach((key) => {
          if(!headers.find((header) => header == key)){
            headers.push(key)
          }
        })
      })
    }
    return headers;
  }
}
```

```
<div class="play-container">

<h1>Child</h1>
    <table border>
         <thead>
              <tr>           
                <th *ngFor="let header of getHeaders()">{{header}}</th>
              </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
              <tr *ngFor="let item of dataMessageResults">           
                <td *ngFor="let key of getHeaders()">{{item[key]}}</td>
              </tr>
         </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: you're right. It should be an array and it is. I've been thinking about it the wrong way!
Unfortunately your getHeaders method didnt work. At least im heading in the right direction now.

Comment: I made some changes and it is working now: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-table-header

Comment: wow. this is much better and more testable than my solution which involved slicing arrays in order to iterate through only the first object. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```js
<div class="play-container">

<h1>Child</h1>
    <table>
         <thead>
              <tr>           
                <th *ngFor="let list of dataMessageResults">{{list.key | keyvalue}}</th>
              </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
              <tr *ngFor="let item of dataMessageResults">           
                <td *ngFor="let list of item ">{{list.value | keyvalue}}</td>
              </tr>
         </tbody>
    </table>
```

update my answer,please check it.

Comment: this returns an error. "Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays."

Answer (score 0):

I've almost gotten it to work with

```
<h1>Child</h1>
        <table>
             <thead>
                  <tr *ngFor="let message of dataMessageResults">           
                    <th *ngFor="let item of message | keyvalue">{{item.key}}</th>
                  </tr>
             </thead>
             <tbody>
                  <tr *ngFor="let message of dataMessageResults">           
                    <td *ngFor="let item of message | keyvalue">{{item.value}}</td>
                  </tr>
             </tbody>
        </table>
```

But I cannot figure out how I can specify that I only want to iterate through the headers once.

```
<tr *ngFor="let message of dataMessageResults[0]">
```

does not work.

Answer (score -1):

```
<h1>Child</h1>
    <table>
         <thead>
              <tr *ngFor="let item of dataMessageResults | keyvalue">           
                <th>{{item.key}}</th>
              </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
              <tr *ngFor="let item of dataMessageResults | keyvalue">           
                <td>{{item.value}}</td>
              </tr>
         </tbody>
    </table>
```