# Angular Display ngFor every item in array items

Tags: html, angular, ngfor

My array looks like this:

```
items = [{name: "jean", surname: "kruger"}, {name: "bobby", surname: "marais"}];
```

How do I display each item in a table, dynamically (without using item.name & item.surname). I don't understand why this code doesn't work:

```
<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let item of items">           
    <td *ngFor="let list of item">{{list}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35534959/access-key-and-value-of-object-using-ngfor

Comment: please check this link hint about ng-For                        https://netbasal.com/angular-2-ngfor-array-with-unique-values-6b15478d6484