# how to access complex json object angular 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angular, angular2-http

```js
//component.ts
public items: any;

getResult(){
    var jsonBody = {};
    jsonBody['activity'] = this.activity;
    jsonBody['seatnumber'] = this.seatNo;

    this.localService.postCall(jsonBody)
        .subscribe(
            data => {
                if (data.message === 'ok') {
                    this.items = data.data.result;
                    console.log(data.data);
                    // window.localStorage.setItem('result',data);
                }
            },
            error => {

            })
}

//localService.ts
postCall(jsonBody){
    const headers = new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Source': 'WEB'
    });
    return this.http.post(this.apiUrl, { body: jsonBody }, { headers: headers })
        .map(data => {
            return data.json();
        },
            error =>
                console.log('unknown error')
        );
}

//json object
{
    "status": true,
        "message": "ok",
            "data": {
        "result": [
            {
                "arts": "75",
                "studentname": "Archana Kol",
                "district": "SIDHI",
                "gender": "F",
                "agri": "70",
                "us": "85",
                "fa": "75",
                "medium": "Hindi",
                "tech": "60",
                "hs": "75",
                "SchoolDies": "23170515307",
                "com": "75",
                "seatnumber": 180734668
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
    {{ item }}
</div>
```

hello, i am using angular 2, I want to loop through this JSON object. I am able to print this object on console but when I loop this object ngfor this will display me this error "Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays." how can I solve this. thank you

Comment: This might help:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35534959/access-key-and-value-of-object-using-ngfor

Answer (score 0):

When you are first starting the component, your `items` variable is equal to `undefined`, which isn't iterable.

There's some solutions for that:

1. change `public items:any;` for `public items:any[] = [];`
2. use `async` pipe:
   in `ngOnInit`:

   ```
   const headers = new Headers({
     'Content-Type': 'application/json',
     'Source': 'WEB'
   });
   this.items$ = this.http.post(this.apiUrl, { body: jsonBody }, { headers: headers })
     .map(data => {
       return data.json();
     },
     error =>
       console.log('unknown error')
   );
   ```

Then change items for `items$: Observable<any[]>`;

And finally, change your binding from `*ngFor="let item of items"` to `*ngFor="let item of items | async"`

You can also wrap the *ngFor in a `<div *ngIf="items !== undefined">...</div>`.