# Best way to display a json object in a json object in Angular 2 release 6

Tags: html, json, angular, typescript

I am working on converting an old Angular 1.X website to Angular 2 release 6.  I've been creating a component class with corresponding html but i'm stuck at the point of displaying a json object inside of another json object. The json object I'm trying to display is

Details Obj :

```
    {
        "details":
        {
            "id": "36d610ed0c62bafd",
            "Field Name": "FID,Shape,OID_,BankPositi",
            "Geometry Type": "Point",
        },
     }
```

And the old code that displayed this was:
HTML :

```
    <div ng-show="vm.item.showDetails" ng-repeat="(key, val) in vm.item.details">
        <p><span>{{key}}:</span>{{val}}</p>
    </div>
```

Javascript :

```
        vm.showDetails = function (entry) {
            entry.showDetails = !entry.showDetails;
            entry.numberOfWords = entry.showDetails ? config.search.showAll : config.search.numberOfWordsShown;
        }
```

What I'm wondering is what is the best way to iterate through the json obj and display it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [access key and value of object using \*ngFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35534959/access-key-and-value-of-object-using-ngfor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about simply

```
<pre>
  {{ yourObject | json }}
</pre>
```

Running example here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ux1xst?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: that's en-genius, cant believe I missed that.  Thank you.