# Angular Object.key - Retrieve,get only one property from object

Tags: angular, object, properties

How can i retrieve only one property from object?

in this example i have object with 2 properties: name and id

```
   <div *ngFor="let post of objectKeys(_postArrayMatch.team1)">
      Team1: {{ _postArrayMatch.team1[post]}}
    </div>
```

I want to exclude the id, how can i show only the name property?

I tried to do something like this, but it doesn't work that way

```
   <div *ngFor="let post of objectKeys(_postArrayMatch.team1)">
    Team1: {{ _postArrayMatch.team1[post].name}} 
 </div>
```

In response i just get empty

Team1:

Team1:

Comment: what `objectKeys` function does and  what `_postArrayMatch.team1` has?

Comment: in components.ts - `objectKeys = Object.keys;` ` `_postArrayMatch.team1` has   `team1: {
    name:string;
    id:number;
  };`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show only one element, don't use `*ngFor`. ngFor is for looping over multiple elements in an iterable.

```
<div>
  Team1: {{ _postArrayMatch.team1.name}}
</div>
```

Comment: then how can i retrieve data without looping?