# Angular 2 Access value from map using known key inside template

Tags: angular, angular2-template

How to get value from map if I know the key and get it like `map[key]` and tried `myMap.get(key)`.

Might be duplicate of [access key and value of object using *ngFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35534959/access-key-and-value-of-object-using-ngfor?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) and https://stackoverflow.com/a/45233924/1225526

But a small change in my scenario, I know the key, I have map like :

```
priority: Map<number, string> = new Map<number, string>();

ngOnInit() {
    this.priority.set(1, Packages.PRIORITY_TYPES.highest);
    this.priority.set(2, Packages.PRIORITY_TYPES.high);
    this.priority.set(3, Packages.PRIORITY_TYPES.medium);
    this.priority.set(4, Packages.PRIORITY_TYPES.low);
    this.priority.set(5, Packages.PRIORITY_TYPES.info);
}
```

I am trying to get the value in my template like `{{priority[item.priority]}}` here `item.priority` has the key value

```
<span [ngClass]="'baseline-text-'+ priority.get(item.priority)">
  {{priority[item.priority]}}</span>    <-- looks like wrong syntax i am not getting the value in my html
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: Maybe you only need an object instead a map

Comment: If you are showing this on a ngFor, you can use `KeyValuePipe` https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the same way you got it in your span class, you must do:

```
{{ priority.get(item.priority) }}
```

Comment: template throws unexpected token for get method but works thanks

Comment: This couldn't be the way, because it's bad practice to call a method on a template, https://dzone.com/articles/why-we-shound-not-use-function-inside-angular-temp

Answer (score 1):

write a pipe like this:

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
  name: 'mapValue'
})
export class MapValuePipe  implements PipeTransform{
  transform<K,V>(map: Map<K,V>,key: K): V {
    return map.get(key);
  }
}
```

if you want to get value of a key in tempate:

```
{{aMap |mapValue:'a key'}}
```

if you want use ngFor to iterate keys or values,you can write a pipe like above.

Comment: a better way is using built-in pipe "keyvalue"。