# Dynamic object key to display *ngFor in Nativescript with Angular

Tags: angular5, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I have the dataset which has derived from the group by product name as below. I need to iterate the array of object and display the product name with all the size of the product.

**Sample dataset**

```
   [ {
  "TEST 1": [
    {
      "content_id": "88282",
      "product_name": "TEST 1",
      "price": "36.00",
      "size" : "XL"
    },
    {
      "content_id": "88283",
      "product_name": "TEST 1",
      "price": "37.00",
      "size" : "XXL"
    }
  }],

{
  "TEST 2": [
    {
      "content_id": "882821",
      "product_name": "TEST 2",
      "price": "36.00",
      "size" : "XL"
    },
    {
      "content_id": "882832",
      "product_name": "TEST 2",
      "price": "37.00",
      "size" : "XXL"
    }]
]
```

I need to iterate the above result and need to display as Product name with all sizes such as "TEST 1 (XL XXL ) and TEST 2 (XL XXL)

**What I am trying is**

<----- need to display here --------->

Comment: There is already a thread with nice examples https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35534959/access-key-and-value-of-object-using-ngfor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get keys or use [foreach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to iterate json.
E.g.

```
const object1 = {"data":
        [ {  "TEST 1": [    {
      "content_id": "88282",
      "product_name": "TEST 1",
      "price": "36.00",
      "size" : "XL"
    },    {
      "content_id": "88283",
      "product_name": "TEST 1",
      "price": "37.00",
      "size" : "XXL"
    }
  ]
}
]


};

object1[Object.keys(object1)[0]].forEach(function(element) {
  console.log(element);
});
```