# How to fetch value from nested json objects in angular 6 dynamically?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6

I want to access data inside json file which contains multiple nested objects and I want to print them dynamically without thinking what is the data inside it. I want to print key values inside dynamically.

my json

```
 {
  "name" : "abc",
  "tags" : "def",
  "updated-by" : "ijk",
  "property" : {
    "description" : "abcd",
    "type" : "string"
  },
  "sources" : {
    "input" : {
      "type" : "lmn",
      "properties" : {
        "key" : "opq"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If my key contains object then it should go inside that object and then prints its values but if it is also another object then it should go inside that object also and then print its key value.It should loop dynamically. Code must be in angular 4 or above.If anyone can help.

Comment: please show us what you have already tried / searched to accomplish this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterate through Nested JavaScript Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8085004/iterate-through-nested-javascript-objects)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I pretty-print JSON using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810841/how-can-i-pretty-print-json-using-javascript)

Comment: I tried to follow this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54760044/how-to-fetch-value-from-json-object-in-angular-6/ but it is only giving me key values for first object  but it is not working for nested objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use recursive function.

```
const myObj = {
  "name" : "abc",
  "tags" : "def",
  "updated-by" : "ijk",
  "property" : {
    "description" : "abcd",
    "type" : "string"
  },
  "sources" : {
    "input" : {
      "type" : "lmn",
      "properties" : {
        "key" : "opq"
      }
    }
  }
}

function checkNested(obj) {
    for (let prop in obj) {        
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            if (typeof obj[prop] == "object"){
                console.log(`Key: ${prop}`)
                checkNested(obj[prop]);
            } else {
              console.log(`Key: ${prop} 'value: ${obj[prop]}`)
            }
        }
    }
}


checkNested(myObj)
```

Comment: Hi Oleg, when i am passing my obj to this function it is not printing anything.

Comment: no it is still not working. My code is in angular 7.I am calling this function from same class.

Comment: I add snippet, so you can run it . Also I puit else for showing only flat node

Comment: "ERROR ReferenceError: checkNested is not defined", this error is coming

Comment: It is running now but problem is still not resolved, I need keys also

Comment: This is working perfectly fine. Thank you for your help Oleg

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you are looking for is already covered by `JSON.stringify(jsonObject)` method.

You can also control the spacing and [pretty print the JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#The_space_argument).