# Mapping JSON object to observable for use with ngFor Angular

Tags: angular, components, angular-services, ngfor

I'm attempting to map a JSON object to an observable Interface that I've configured in my angular app, my hope is that once I have it mapped I can use it as an input to loop through an ngFor.

Unfortunately I don't believe I'm configuring either my service correctly, or possible the service call.

I get the json object returned as a single object but the ngFor does not properly loop through the results returned, any assistance in pointing out what I may be overlooking would be greatly appreciated.

// Interface I am trying to access

```
export interface IProduct {
   name: string;
   description: string;
   price: number;
   category: string;
   image: string;
}
```

// Service I am attempting to call

```
private productList = new BehaviorSubject<IProduct[]|null>(null);
productListChanges$ = this.productList.asObservable();
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

getProds(): Observable<IProduct[]> {
     this.productList.next(null);
     return this.http.get<IProduct[]> 
                      ('http://localhost:4200/assets/data/products.json')
     .pipe(
        tap(data => this.productList.next(data)),
     );
 }
```

// Call for the service

```
productsList: IProduct[] = [];

this.productService.getProds().subscribe((response: any) => {
  this.productsList = response.products[0] as IProduct[];
  console.log(this.productsList);
});
```

// Attempt to use ngFor with obtained object

```
<app-product *ngFor="let product of productsList" [prod]="product" ></app-product>
```

// Console log from the service call outputs the following

[logOutput from service call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CJwH.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try with async when looping with Observables.

```
<app-product *ngFor="let product of productsList | async" [prod]="product" ></app-product>
```

Comment: Tried implementing the async, but the only difference is the console log outputs an 'Object' and the ngFor still doesn't run properly

Answer (score 0):

I see you're using HTTP to serve JSON data thats readily avialable as data coming from a static file existing in your assets folder. I would avoid HTTP calls to serve these. I've refactored your code to both serve static data, and also support remote data query using the same service method. It should also help out during unit testing as async testing is a nightmare.

```js
// Changed the Interface to a class
export class Product {
   name: string;
   description: string;
   price: number;
   category: string;
   image: string;
}

// Create a sample-data.ts file
export const ProductListData: Array<Product> = [
    {
       name: 'ProductName',
       description: 'Description',
       price: '9.99', // Maybe should be a number type and not string
       category: 'Test Category',
       image: 'your url for testing'
    }
]

// In service... 
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { ProductListData } from './sample-data';
useSampleData = false;

getProducts(): Observable<Array<Product>> {
    if (useSampleData) {
        // Use this is your want to serve static JSON
        return of(ProductListData); // of() turns your readily avialable object into an obeservable promise
    } else {
    // Get from actual HTTP as async
        return this.http.get<Array<Product>>('http://localhost:4200/api/your-endpoint-url');
    }
 }
 
 
// In you Component...
public productList: Array<Product> = [];

this.productService.getProducts().subscribe(
    productList => {
      this.productsList = productList;
    },
    err => {
        console.log('Error: ', err);
    }
);
```

Your template wouldn't need changing.

Comment: I tried making all the indicated changes but it seems as though the ngFor still isn't building properly... not sure what I'm missing here... it's like the productsList is an Array of objects that the ngFor just isn't appropriately reading?

Comment: Can you share any new errors? Can you put a console.log on the component call to your service, so we can confirm that the objects arrive?

Answer (score 0):

As your console output indicates, `productsList` is an Object, but `ngFor` expects an Array.

If you can change the data, it should be easily doable to change it to an Array (`[...]`) instead of an Object ( `{...}`).

Otherwise you have several options to convert the structure in code to an Array. For example, when using `Object.values()` you can convert your current structure to an Array. Alternatively, you can also use the [KeyValuePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe) available since Angular 6.1. Also answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/51491848/9999800

Comment: This answer actually did it for me, SUCH an oversight, adjusted the products.json itself to be [{},{},{}] instead of { 1: {}, 2:{}, 3:{} }. THANK you so much for your input