# Getting keys and values from json in Angular

Tags: json, angular

I need to get values from json (comes from merged MySQL tables).

I've tried a several solutions from previous topic but none of them worked for me.

[access key and value of object using *ngFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35534959/access-key-and-value-of-object-using-ngfor/51491848#51491848)

my JSON format is:

```
[
   {
      "idemployee":1,
      "name":"Ernest",
      "surename":"Pająk",
      "role":"Obsługa Baru",
      "employeehours":[
         {
            "idemployeehours":1,
            "date":"2019-01-10T23:00:00.000+0000",
            "quantity":8.0
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

and what I got is "Key: 0 and Value: " (answer from Pardeep Jain topic above)

EDIT:
this is my code:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of employee| keyvalue">
Key: <b>{{item.key}}</b> and Value: <b>{{item.value}}</b>
```

employee comes from Angular component and gives mentioned JSON. The problem is getting nested values from "employeehours" (like quantity)

Comment: Please give a [mcve] of how you adapted the existing answers to your specific problem.

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: The link you mention is for iterating object properties (key,value) but according to your data you have plain array of objects. Is that correct?

Comment: well, `employeehours` is an array too, so why would you need to use `keyvalue`?

Comment: Yes, it's array of objects. I don't know if I need to use keyvalue, I just need to put values from "employeehours" (like quantity) to table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `keyvalue` pipe. `employeehours` is an array, so you just need a nested `*ngFor` for the array, so example where you have stored your data in an `employees` array:

```
<div *ngFor="let emp of employees">
  <p>Name: {{emp.name}} {{emp.surename}}</p>
  <div *ngFor="let hour of emp.employeehours">
    <p>Date: {{hour.date | date: 'shortDate'}}</p>
    <p>Quantity: {{hour.quantity}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wj5whz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**

Comment: Thank you ! That was the move

Answer (score 1):

if you run keyValue pipe on array object you got the keys as the index of the values in the array so tha why you need a nested ngFor to run keyvalue pipe on the value of the array

```
<div *ngFor="let item of employee">
    <div *ngFor="let emp of item |keyvalue "> 
        Key: <b>{{emp.key}}</b> and Value: <b>{{emp.value}}</b>
  </div>
</div>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tuyfti)

**UPDATED!**

if you want to support sohow keys value of employeehours where the value is array best cases here to create a component to do all of this and use this component to render the new values like recursion

*component*

```
export class RenderComponent  {

  @Input() items = [];

  isArray(value) {
    return value instanceof Array
  }
}
```

*template*

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
    <div *ngFor="let obj of item | keyvalue " class="well"> 
        Key: <b>{{obj.key}}</b> and Value: <b>{{obj.value}}</b>

        <ng-container *ngIf="isArray(obj.value)">
            <render [items]="obj.value"></render>
        </ng-container>

  </div>
</div>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j2xdvx)

Comment: How about getting only requested values like "quantity" (all from the array) not the every value from object?