# Nested JSON Data in Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

thanks in advance, I am using Ionic 4 for a mobile app and on a page there is a need to list out the nested data but I don't seem to be able to get it right.

Following is the JSON Data

```js
"campaign_performance": {
      "id": 11783,
      "name": "calvinseng.com",
      "mobile": "false",
      "date_from": "2018-01-01",
      "date_to": "2018-01-02",
      "keywords": [
        {
          "id": 235505,
          "name": "hot stamping printing",
          "positions": {
            "2018-01-01": 1,
            "2018-01-02": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "id": 235506,
          "name": "creative agency singapore",
          "positions": {
            "2018-01-01": 59,
            "2018-01-02": 57
          }
        }
       ]
    }
```

and on the page, the html that I did was

```html
    <ion-list color="primary" *ngFor="let campaign of userService.campaign_performance">
      {{ campaign.name }}
        <ng-container *ngFor="let keyword of userService.campaign_performance.keywords">
            {{ keyword.id }}
        </ng-container>
    </ion-list>
```

But the html returned nothing in the View.

Was hoping to achieve something similar as attached. Any idea? 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like its more likely to be:

```
<ion-list color="primary" *ngFor="let campaign of userService.campaign_performance">
  {{ campaign.name }}
    <ng-container *ngFor="let keyword of campaign.keywords">
        {{ keyword.id }}
    </ng-container>
</ion-list>
```

You are looping each `campaign_performance` and assigning it to `campaign`.

So if you want to do an inner loop then you start from that variable and loop its individual contents.

Comment: Thanks! How can I retrieve the value for positions?
With this code I could retrieve the keywords but not the positions
`<ion-list color="primary" *ngFor="let keyword of userService.campaign_performance.keywords">
      <ion-item>
        {{ keyword.name }}
        {{ keyword.positions[0] }}
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>`

Comment: your `kwyword.position` are not Array. you can get simply without `[0]` index.
e.g: `<ion-item> {{ keyword.name }} {{ keyword.positions }} </ion-item>`

Comment: That's a new question to be honest. I've answered your original question, but now you have added on a huge new aspect to this. It seems, the simple answer is there isn't any built in way to do it. The more [complex answer is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35534959/access-key-and-value-of-object-using-ngfor). Perhaps if you need help with that you can open another question and close this as resolved.