# angularjs: How to select first object in object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the object `properties` which contains objects that are all from the same city. In my template I want to display the city name so the order of the items in the object does not matter. How can I select the first property's city name from my AngularJS template?

```
<p>These properties are in {{$ctrl.properties.???.city}}</span>
```

```
properties: {
    '123 Main': {
        city: 'Portland',
        sqft: 2132
    },
    '398 Boardwalk': {
        city: 'Portland',
        sqft: 428
    },
    '20 Broadway': {
        city: 'Portland',
        sqft: 492
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `ng-repeat` directive with the `(key, value)` form and pipe it to the `limitTo` filter:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, obj) in $ctrl.properties | limitTo : 1">
    These properties are in {{key}}
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="(prop, value) in obj">
           {{prop}}:  {{value}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS `ng-repeat` Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)
- [AngularJS `limitTo` Filter API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo)

Comment: Creative, I like it :)

Answer (score 4):

Order of items in objects is not guaranteed, i.e. it might be different each time. But if you just want *any* first object, you can get it by the first key:

```
const firstKey = Object.keys(properties)[0];
return properties[firstKey];
```

Comment: Is there a way for me to do this in the angularjs template. Order of items in object doesn't matter.

Comment: try `{{$ctrl.properties[Object.keys($ctrl.properties)[0]).city}}`

Comment: I think you made a typo and meant to use another closing bracket `]` after the 0. I have tried your solution `{{$ctrl.properties[Object.keys($ctrl.properties)[0]].city}}` but I do not see the city name. Can AngularJS template compute `Object.keys()`? There are no console errors.

Comment: I don't see any data being displayed when I try `{{Obect.keys($ctrl.properties)}}`. This makes me think that AngularJS template is not computing `Obect.keys($ctrl.properties)`.

Comment: Sorry about the typo. And you're right, seems like you'll need to pass `Object.keys` or result of it to your template manually: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42813708. I think the easiest would be to write a filter called `first` and use it in your template.

Comment: No problem. I was hoping to keep my code clean and simple. I can mark your response as the accepted answer if you update response saying that `Object.keys` needs to be passed into the template :)