# Print Key Values In Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript

Consider the dataSet which has table has following rows

**Table**

```
0: {date: "29-October-2019", flow: 0, max: 155.98, min: 155.98, avg: 155.98}
1: {date: "30-October-2019", flow (cft): 0, max: 27.03, min: 27.03, avg: 27.03}
```

Now I would like to iterate this each row and print all its columns in Angular like concept in c#

```
   @foreach (DataRow row in Model.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
                        <tr>

                            @foreach (DataColumn column in Model.Tables[0].Columns)
            {

                                <td>

                                    @row[column.ColumnName]

                                </td>
                            }

                        </tr>
                    }
```

Currently I am doing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35534959/access-key-and-value-of-object-using-ngfor)

> objectValues = Object.values;

```
    <tr *ngFor="let row of  dataSet.table.length">

            <td *ngFor="let val of objectValues(row)">
                {{row[val]}}
             </td>
         </tr>
```

but this throws

[image]

Please help.

Comment: Where are you assigning objectValues(row) values?

Comment: inside the loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[As Angular docs says:](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe)

> Transforms Object or Map into an array of key value pairs.

Use built in pipe for the same named as `keyvalue` pipe to iterate through objects:

```
<tr *ngFor="let row of  dataSet.table  | keyvalue">
    <td *ngFor="let val of row | keyvalue">
       {{row[val]}}
    </td>
</tr>
```

**UPDATE:**

You have array of objects. So you can use just simple `*ngFor`:

HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of arr">
    {{item?.min}}
    <!--{{item | json}}-->     
</div>
```

TypeScript:

```
export class AppComponent {
  arr = [
    {date: "29-October-2019", flow: 0, max: 155.98, min: 155.98, avg: 155.98},
    {date: "30-October-2019", flow : 0, max: 27.03, min: 27.03, avg: 27.03}
  ];
}
```

Please, see [a stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-key-val-pipe-ykjt3q?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

Comment: do I need to create pipe class inside ts file?

Comment: error is same Cannot find a differ supporting object '2'

Comment: thank you so much for your help I solved it by  <tr *ngFor="let row of  dailyFlowDataSet.table1">
                  <td *ngFor="let item of  row | keyvalue">
                    {{item.value}}
                  </td>
              </tr>   and a vote up for you