# How to extract keys from JSON where its value is true

Tags: html, json, angular

**I have below JSON, from this I want to extract Skills where it is true.**

```
[  
   {  
      "_id":"5de9f351baca28556c6a4b71",
      "Name":"Harsha",
      "Age":20,
      "Gender":"M",
      "Skills":{  
         "Java":"",
         "Mule":true,
         "Angular":""
      }
   },
   {  
      "_id":"5de9f358baca28556c6a4b72",
      "Name":"Anji",
      "Age":21,
      "Gender":"M",
      "Skills":{  
         "Java":"",
         "Mule":true,
         "Angular":true
      }
   },
   {  
      "_id":"5dea110297c2b65298b136e4",
      "Name":"Abhi",
      "Age":25,
      "Gender":"M",
      "Skills":{  
         "Java":"",
         "Mule":true,
         "Angular":""
      }
   }
]
```

**I am able to print rest of the data using below code**

```
<table *ngIf="formTemplate">
        <tr>
            <th *ngFor="let header of questionTitleArray" >{{header}}</th>
        </tr>

        <tr *ngFor="let data of surveyDataFromDB">
                <ng-container *ngFor="let head of questionTitleArray">
                <td>{{data[head]}}</td>         
        </ng-container>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

(Here JSON is "surveyDataFromDB")

**Below is the output I am getting**

```
Name    Age Gender  Skills
Harsha  20  M   [object Object]
Anji    21  M   [object Object]
Abhi    25  M   [object Object]
```

**I want Skills which are true in place of [object Object]. Please help.**

Comment: You need sth like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35534959/access-key-and-value-of-object-using-ngfor) another ng for printing skills

Comment: Try this one `Object.keys(skills).filter((skill) => {return skills[skill] == true;});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<table>
            <tr>
              <th *ngFor="let header of questionTitleArray">{{ header }} </th>
            </tr>
            <tr *ngFor="let data of surveyDataFromDB">
                    <ng-container *ngFor="let head of questionTitleArray">
                     <span *ngIf="checkType(data[head]) else elsePart">
                        <span *ngFor="let j of data[head] | keyvalue">
                           <td *ngIf="j.value==true">
                                {{j.key}} 
                           </td>
                        </span>
                     </span>
                     <ng-template #elsePart>
                         <td>{{data[head]}}</td> 
                     </ng-template>    
                   </ng-container>
                 </tr>
          </table>
```

**in ts:**

```
checkType(Ob:any)
 {
  if(typeof (Ob) === 'object')
  return true;
  else
  return false;
 }
```

Comment: Okay so you used checktype for checking the type perfact!!

Comment: I wouldn't call that perfect https://dzone.com/articles/why-we-shound-not-use-function-inside-angular-temp

Answer (score 4):

You can first map your object to only have the truthy ones. You can use lodash pickBy.

```
mappedSurveyDataFromDB = this.surveyDataFromDB.map(
    entry => ({...entry, Skills: _pickBy(entry.Skills, Boolean)}),
  );
```

After change the template like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th *ngFor="let header of questionTitleArray">{{ header }}</th>
  </tr>

  <tr *ngFor="let data of mappedSurveyDataFromDB">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let head of questionTitleArray">
      <td *ngIf="head !== 'Skills'">{{ data[head] }}</td>
      <td *ngIf="head === 'Skills'">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let entry of (data[head] | keyvalue); let last = last">
          {{ entry.key }}
          <ng-container *ngIf="!last">, </ng-container>
        </ng-container>
      </td>       
    </ng-container>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ga7lqg

Comment: It gave me exactly what I need. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: It is working perfectly if we have "Skills" in JSON. But what if we want to make your approach dynamic. There can be other name for the object which is currently referred as "Skills". Please help.

Comment: I guess you need to do a mix of my answer and the one from 'Yash Rami'. (typeof)

Answer (score 2):

you can try like this

```
<table *ngIf="formTemplate">
        <tr>
            <th *ngFor="let header of questionTitleArray" >{{header}}</th>
        </tr>

        <tr *ngFor="let data of surveyDataFromDB">
                <ng-container *ngFor="let head of questionTitleArray">
// here we are iterating a loop with keyvalue pipe bcs "Skills" is object
                 <span *ngIf="typeOf(data[head]) === 'object' else elsePart">
                    <td *ngFor="let j of data[head] | keyvalue">
                          {{j.key}} {{j.value}}
                    <td>
                 </span>
                 <ng-template #elsePart>
                     {{data[head]}}
                 <ng-template>    
               </ng-container>
             </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: ERROR TypeError: _co.typeof is not a function

Comment: Your code is true dynamic with some changes. because of ERROR "TypeError: _co.typeof is not a function" we have to create a function in ts checkType(Ob:any)
 {
  if(typeof (Ob) === 'object')
  return true;
  else
  return false;
 }

Comment: Good to know  suggests me changes so i will update my answer

Comment: See my own ans.

Answer (score 1):

You can process before render on ui, and create a comma seprated string of skill key on the basics of its value

```js
let list=[{"_id":"5de9f351baca28556c6a4b71","Name":"Harsha","Age":20,"Gender":"M","Skills":{"Java":"","Mule":true,"Angular":""}},{"_id":"5de9f358baca28556c6a4b72","Name":"Anji","Age":21,"Gender":"M","Skills":{"Java":"","Mule":true,"Angular":true}},{"_id":"5dea110297c2b65298b136e4","Name":"Abhi","Age":25,"Gender":"M","Skills":{"Java":"","Mule":true,"Angular":""}}];


let result = list.map((o) => { return {...o, 'Skills': Object.entries(o.Skills).reduce((acc, i) => acc+= i[1] ? `${i[0]},`: '' , '').slice(0, -1) } });

console.log(result)
```

Or **You can checkout this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rfij32) may this helps you**

In **template** you can use [KeyValuePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe) to iterate on `object` i.e skills and show skill key only when its value is not `falsy`

```
 <ng-container *ngFor="let entry of (data[head] | keyvalue); let last = last">
          {{  entry.value ? entry.key: '' }}
          <ng-container *ngIf="!last && entry.value">,</ng-container>
        </ng-container>
```

Comment: But what if we want to make your approach dynamic. There can be other name for the object which is currently referred as "Skills" or there can be multiple objects like "Skills" in the json.

Answer (score 1):

**`Skills`** attribute in your data is an **`Object`**. **`ngFor`** can only be used with **`Iteratable`**. Therefore first you should convert **`Skills`** to an **`Array`**. It can be done as below.

```
  dataForView: any[];

  prepareDataForView() {

    this.dataForView = [...this.surveyDataFromDB];
    this.dataForView.map(item => {
      item.Skills = Object.keys(item.Skills).map(key => {
        if (item.Skills[key]) {
          return key;
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

And then you bind new array to **`View`**.

Find working **[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zekp2e?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**.

Comment: Instead of hard-coding the "item.Skills" can we have any dynamic approach for this?

Answer (score 0):

Okey so you want to extract all the skills that are true and place them in a new object. From what I know there is not built in function to do this, however I wrote some code to to exactly this

```js
var skills = {
    Java: "",
    Mule: true,
    Angular: "",
    Cpp: true,
    Maja: false,
    NodeJs: true
}

let keys = Object.keys(skills);
let trueSkills = {};
keys.forEach(keyValue => {
    if (skills[keyValue] == true)
        trueSkills[keyValue] = true;
});

console.log(trueSkills); // These are all the true skills
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Err.. no it doesn't. You need to use the object from the question and not create your own.

Answer (score 0):

Dealing with object keys based on their values can be complex in an Angular template. You could try to transform "Skills" into an array of strings. For example you could do it like this:

```
get formattedData() {
  // this.data would be your json object
  return this.data.map(i => ({...i, Skills: Object.keys(i.Skills).filter(j => i.Skills[j] === true)}))
}
```

This loops through every entry and transforms the skills object into an array with the skills.

This would return:

```
[
   {
      "_id":"5de9f351baca28556c6a4b71",
      "Name":"Harsha",
      "Age":20,
      "Gender":"M",
      "Skills":[
         "Mule"
      ]
   },
   {
      "_id":"5de9f358baca28556c6a4b72",
      "Name":"Anji",
      "Age":21,
      "Gender":"M",
      "Skills":[
         "Mule",
         "Angular"
      ]
   },
   {
      "_id":"5dea110297c2b65298b136e4",
      "Name":"Abhi",
      "Age":25,
      "Gender":"M",
      "Skills":[
         "Mule"
      ]
   }
]
```

A minimal working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wnmde7)

I would strongly advise against this method though, if you have a lot of entries as it would take a long time.