# Iterate through an object key in Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, loops, object, ngfor

I am having this object:

```
protected products: { 
 [key: string]: {
  color: string,
  brand: string,
 };
} = {};

products =  {
 scan12345: {color: "Orange", brand: "X"},
 scan13813: {color: "Pink", brand: "X"},
}
```

How can I iterate through this project in my component Tempate? I tried:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let pro of products">
   {{ pro.color }}
</ion-item>
```

Comment: to run loop using `*ngFor` you should have array, you can not run loop on object.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [access key and value of object using \*ngFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35534959/access-key-and-value-of-object-using-ngfor)

Comment: @piyushjain You can using `keyvalue` pipe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the KeyValuePipe:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let pro of products | keyvalue">
   {{ pro.value.color }}
</ion-item>
```

Documentation: https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe