# Iterate through object key in Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, object, angular5

I am having this object:

```
protected products: { 
 [key: string]: {
  color: string,
  brand: string,
 };
} = {};

products =  {
 scan12345: {color: "Orange", brand: "X"},
 scan13813: {color: "Pink", brand: "X"},
}
```

How can I iterate through this project in my component Tempate? I tried:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let pro of products">
   {{ pro.color }}
</ion-item>
```

In a project that I use Angular 8, keyValue pipeline worked. What can I do here?
I am using "target": "es2015".

Comment: can you please create stackblitz

Comment: Create a custom pipe as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35536052/6513921

Comment: @MichaelD good solution but as I read it has performance issues.

Comment: Could you please say what kind of performance issues?

Comment: A good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60415556/6166191

Comment: @JózsefCserkó: `keyvalue` pipe is not available in Angular 5

Comment: @MichaelD It creates huge performance bottleneck because it needs to generate the collection every time the change detector checks for changes

Comment: @MichaelD Sorry. She can cast the object to array too.

Comment: @MichaelD any other ideas?

Comment: @KathrineHanson: Apart from the answer below, I can't think of any for your object structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use the keys of your object to loop through:

```
products =  {
  scan12345: {color: "Orange", brand: "X"},
  scan13813: {color: "Pink", brand: "X"},
}
this.productKeys = Object.keys(products);
```

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let key of productKeys">
   {{ products[key].color }}
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [KeyValuePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe), see the detail

Use the same object as you have:

```
products =  {
  scan12345: {color: "Orange", brand: "X"},
  scan13813: {color: "Pink", brand: "X"},
}
```

Then your HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of products | keyvalue">
      Single Object: {{item.key}}:{{item.value}} <br>
      Color: {{item.value.color}} <br>
      Brand: {{item.value.brand}}
</div>
```