# How can I get data from a dynamic object

Tags: angular

```
[
  {
    "title": "Battery",
    "sections": {
      "Capacity": "2",
      "Type": "1"
    }
  },
  {
    "title": "Процесор",
    "sections": {
      "Number of nuclei": "22",
      "Processor name": "33",
      "Frequency": "11"
    }
  },
  {
    "title": "Display",
    "sections": {
      "The type of matrix": "222",
      "Screen diagonal": "111"
    }
  }
]
```

How can I get data from it (In the template):

Title: (Battery)

key ------------------------> value:

capacity -------------> 2

type -----------------> 1

Title 2: (Processor)

key ------------------------> value

Title 3: (Display)

key ------------------------> value

Comment: Do you wish to loop in the template or the controller?

Comment: @MichaelD in the template

Comment: Maybe this ist what you're looking for. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51491848/7600725

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`keyvalue`](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe) pipe. Try the following

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of obj">
  Title - {{ item.title }}
  <div *ngFor="let section of item.sections | keyvalue">
    {{ section.key }} - {{ section.value }}
  </div>
  <br>
</div>
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dvu4fz)

Note: `keyvalue` pipe was introduced in Angular v6.1.0. A solution for earlier versions could be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35536052/6513921).