# Iterate through array of objects using *ngFor of angular

Tags: arrays, angular, object, key-value, ngfor

The array consists of a key and value pair of objects.i want iterate through to fetch key and values of object.

```
var arr = [{fruit: banana},{color: red},{city: London},{count: 10},{price: 100$}];
```

i tried using keyvalue pipe

```
<div class="bx--row" *ngFor="let obj of arr | keyvalue; let i = index;">
     <span class="bx--col-xs-5 bx--col-md-5"> {{obj.key}} :</span>
     <span class="bx--col-xs-5 bx--col-md-5">{{obj.value}} </span>
</div>
```

Expected result:

```
fruit : banana
color: red
city: London
count : 10
price : 100$
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [access key and value of object using \*ngFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35534959/access-key-and-value-of-object-using-ngfor)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need two `*ngFor` directives. Try the following

```html
<div class="bx--row" *ngFor="let obj of arr; let i = index;">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of obj | keyvalue">
    <span class="bx--col-xs-5 bx--col-md-5"> {{item.key}} :</span>
    <span class="bx--col-xs-5 bx--col-md-5">{{item.value}} </span>
  <ng-container>
</div>
```

Or you could merge the individual objects to a single object in the controller and iterate it with a single `*ngFor`.

Controller

```js
const arr = [{fruit: 'banana'},{color: 'red'},{city: 'London'},{count: 10},{price: '100$'}];
const obj = Object.assign({}, ...arr)
```

Template

```html
<div class="bx--row" *ngFor="let item of obj | keyvalue; let i = index;">
  <span class="bx--col-xs-5 bx--col-md-5"> {{item.key}} :</span>
  <span class="bx--col-xs-5 bx--col-md-5">{{item.value}} </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

in html

```
<div class="bx--row" *ngFor="let obj of arr">
     <span class="bx--col-xs-5 bx--col-md-5"> {{objectKeys(obj)}} :</span>
     <span class="bx--col-xs-5 bx--col-md-5">{{obj[objectKeys(obj)]}} </span>
</div>
```

in ts

```
objectKeys(obj){
 return Object.keys(obj)[0];
}
```