# How to get value from JSON object using index in Angular

Tags: json, angular

I have a configuration like the following in the component file :

```
  public status: any = {
    PRG: "In Progress",
    COMP: "Completed",
    FAIL: "Failed",
  };
```

Now in the template file I have a loop and in there, the status is coming as one of the field. I am trying to access value from `status` like the following:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of items">
    <td>{{ config[item.status] }}</td>
</tr>
```

But I am not getting any value here. How to access the value from JSON object ?

UPDATE: My `items` looks like the following:

```
[
   {
      "id":3,
      "description":"Description",
      "status":"COMP",
      "user_id":"user2"
   },
   {
      "id":4,
      "description":"Description",
      "status":"INPRG",
      "user_id":"user2"
   }
]
```

and the HTML looks like the following :

```
<div class="d-flex arm-release_status badge{{configurations[item.status]}}">
      <p>{{status[item.status]}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35534959/access-key-and-value-of-object-using-ngfor

Comment: Can you post how your items look like?

Comment: @Sajeetharan it's just an array of objects. I have updated the question

Comment: It's working fine https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dqpyjo?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: then its not an issue with the values , post your complete HTML

Comment: I am already using the value once to specify the color. The HTML is something like this : `<div
                                                    class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center rm-release_status-badge {{configurations[release.release_status]}}">
                                                    <p>{{status[release.release_status]}}</p>
                                                </div>`

Comment: @Sajeetharan why is your example demo print only one of them even there are two elements ?

Comment: @Sajeetharan I have updated question with HTML

Comment: you are doing silly mistakes , my code print only value because values you provided in the items and status dont match. 2nd you are just using in the class which wont work

Answer (score 0):

You are using a `config` property that doesn't seem to exist, use `status` instead.

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of items">
  <td>{{ status[item.status] }}</td>
</tr>
```

PS: To also add a class use something like

```
<div [ngClass]='"badge-"+status[item.status].toLowerCase()'>
      <p>{{status[item.status]}}</p>
</div>
```