# How to send parameters of *ngFor on click in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a running Angular application and want to send the data on click from html template as:

**.ts**

```
columns: [
           { label: 'User Name', key: 'Name' },
           { label: 'User Age', key: 'Age' }
         ]

data: [
    {Name: 'John', Age: 12},
    {Name: 'Sam', Age: 34},
    {Name: 'Jack', Age: 15}
]

onClick(data) {
   console.log(data);
}
```

**html**

```
<div *ngFor="let row of data">
     <div *ngFor="let column of columns" (click)="onClick(row[column.key])">
         {{ row[column.key] }}
      </div>
</div>
```

But, I am not able to fetch the data and getting value as undefined.
Please help me on this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [access key and value of object using \*ngFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35534959/access-key-and-value-of-object-using-ngfor)

Comment: what is the `{{ row[column.key] }}` in the template showing you?  is it also showing "undefined"?  get that to work first... then your onClick will follow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assignment operator is  **=** to not **:**

u want to assign arrays to columns and data so u should use **=**

```
columns = [
           { label: 'User Name', key: 'Name' },
           { label: 'User Age', key: 'Age' }
         ]

data= [
    {Name: 'John', Age: 12},
    {Name: 'Sam', Age: 34},
    {Name: 'Jack', Age: 15}
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I made small change, I hope it will work for you.

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-01wg3

```js
columns= [
           { label: 'User Name', key: 'Name' },
           { label: 'User Age', key: 'Age' }
         ]

data= [
    {Name: 'John', Age: 12},
    {Name: 'Sam', Age: 34},
    {Name: 'Jack', Age: 15}
]

onClick(data) {
   console.log(data);
}
```

```html
<div *ngFor="let row of data">
     <div *ngFor="let column of columns" (click)="onClick(row[column.key])">
         {{ row[column.key] }}
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: columns is an array, you souldn't use | keyvalue