# how to access objects property name in angular template?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to bind a nested objects property name  using angular interpolation

```
 <ng-container ngFor="let item of saleDetailsAggegater.productMap | keyvalue">
                            <tr *ngFor="let qtyMap of item.value | keyvalue">
                              <td>{{ item.key }}</td>
                              <td>{{qtyMap.value}}</td>
                              <td>{{Object.keys(qtyMap)[0]}}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </ng-container>
```

my saledetailsAggegater object is as follows

```
{"productMap":{"55478":{"priceQuantityMap":{"200.00":10}}},"taxMap":{},"paymentMap":{"1":970},"total":970}
```

but this line is not working as expected

```
<td>{{Object.keys(qtyMap)[0]}}</td>
```

how can i achieve this?

Comment: What is not working as expected? What is the expected outcome? I don't think you can use native javascript functions (like `Object.keys`) in your template

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35534959/access-key-and-value-of-object-using-ngfor

Comment: What do you want to achieve by `Object.keys(qtyMap)[0]`?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can use native javascript functions in your template (angular won't parse them). You can however define the function on your component, and then use that in your template:

```
@Component({
  template: '<td>{{objectKeys(myObj)[0]}}</td>'
})
export class MyComponent {
  objectKeys = Object.keys;

  myObj = { displayThisKey: 'some-value' };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

first you have a typo in your first `ngFor`, you forgot to put the `*`.
and you can achieve what you want by doing the following:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of saleDetailsAggegater.productMap | keyvalue">
    <tr *ngFor="let qtyMap of item.value | keyvalue">
        <td>{{ item.key }}</td>
        <td>{{qtyMap.value | json}}</td>
        <td>{{qtyMap.key | json}}</td>
        <td>{{(qtyMap.value | keyvalue | json)}}</td>
    <td *ngFor="let qty of (qtyMap.value | keyvalue);">
      {{qty.key}}
    </td>
    </tr>
</ng-container>
```

I deleted {{Object.keys(qtyMap)[0]}} and added a json pipe just to make sure the object has the values you wanted.
I also added multiple possibilities for you to choose from.
and here is a live demo: [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ulyob1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)