# Angular ngFor is not available for my object

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ngfor

I have an Ionic app with Angular and want to iterate through an array of objects that I get from an API.

When I log `sale.waver` (waver contains the array) to my console I get l my infos but when I try to use *ngFor I get an error. I use sale? because the app has to first get the data from the API and until then sale.waver is not defined.

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let eintrag of sale?.waver">
  xxx       
</ion-item>
```

This is the log of `sale.waver` and the error from the *ngFor.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Your `sale.waver` is not an array, it's an object (even though it has numbered keys). As the error says, `*ngFor` only works with [Iterables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols).

You could change the type of `sale.waver` to array or try to make it iterable by adding a `[Symbol.iterator]` property to it (see this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols)).

Comment: Thanks, this info got me on the right track and I found this, which solved the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35534959/access-key-and-value-of-object-using-ngfor

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the item is there or not first and then add the condition. Something like this

```
// Assuming sale.waver is an array. Otherwise the answer provided by Kirill holds good here

<ng-container *ngIf="sale && sale.waver">
  <ion-item *ngFor="let eintrag of sale?.waver">
     xxx       
  </ion-item>
</ng-container>

// 1) You need ng-container because you cant use *ngIf and *ngFor on the same tag
// 2) The ion-item tag will render only if sale and sale.waver are present.
```