# NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays. Angular 12 error

Tags: html, arrays, angular, loops, object

```
paymentOptions = 
[
  {
    "key":"COD",
    "value":"COD"
  },
  {
    "key":"ONLINE",
    "value":"ONLINE"
  }
];
```

I have an array of objects in my component ts file when I loop it in html file using ngFor

```html
<div *ngFor="let obj of paymentOptions">
    <input type="checkbox" value = "{{obj.value}}">{{obj.key}}
</div>
```

My data print but I get an error in console as
Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Comment: I do not see a problem in your code. Could you check maybe there is another *ngFor in your code which might be iterating on an object instead of an array?

Comment: yes I have another loop and when I comment that loop I dont see any error

Comment: Please suggest some solution

Comment: For Objects, there is a pipe available, refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35534959/access-key-and-value-of-object-using-ngfor

Answer (score 0):

```
public payngFor=[];

paymentOptions.foreach(element =>{

  payngFor.push(element);

});
```

and in HTML loop the payngFor it will work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like below

```
<div *ngFor="let obj of paymentOptions">
    <input type="checkbox" [value]="obj.value">{{obj.key}}
</div>
```

For more details refer below links
[binding-syntax](https://angular.io/guide/binding-syntax), [interpolation](https://angular.io/guide/interpolation), [template-statements](https://angular.io/guide/template-statements)

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type
> 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Your provided code doesnt reproduce the error. I assume there is another loop in your template trying to Iterate over incompatible data type.

Reason for this error is basically you are trying iterate over a string, object or any other sort of data type rather than the type being an array. It gets thrown from template where you are using `*ngFor`.

Please refer to sample [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-j6yxre?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/app.component.html) code snipet here