# Parse value from object in Angular template

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

#object

```json
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "description": "1 - Gulf Coast"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "description": "10 - West Great Lakes"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "description": "11 - California"
    },
]
```

#html code

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill" >
    <mat-label>Region</mat-label>
    <mat-select [(ngModel)]="territoryAssignmentFields.region" name="region">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let region of regions" [value]="region.id">{{ region.description }}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

How do we parse on the angular template that the value of mat-select option will be the id from the description object for example based on the object below the `[value]` should be:

> 1, 10, 11.

It should get the id or number from the description and then use it as `[value]` of mat-select option.

Can we parse that on the template? Thanks.

#tscode

```js
getregion() {
  this.searchString = "";
  this._pickListService.getregion(this.accountId,this.searchString).subscribe(
    res => {
      this.regions = res.data;
      console.log(" this.regions",  this.regions) 
    },
    err => {
      console.log('Filtered Territory Assignments Region Error')
      console.log(err);
    }
  )
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35534959/access-key-and-value-of-object-using-ngfor  check this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In subscribe event, with `Array.map()` to generate a new array with id:

1. Split `description` value by `-` sign.
2. Get the first value from (1).
3. Trim spacing from (2).
4. Cast to `number` type from (3).

```js
this._pickListService
  .getregion(this.accountId, this.searchString)
  .subscribe(
    (res) => {
      let data: any[] = res.data.map((x: any) => {
        return {
          id: parseInt(x.description.split('-')[0].trim()),
          description: x.description
        };
      });

      this.regions = data;
      console.log(' this.regions', this.regions);
    },
    (err) => {
      console.log('Filtered Territory Assignments Region Error');
      console.log(err);
    }
  );
```

[Sample Demo on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wnyhko?file=src/app/app.component.ts)