# angular 2 how do i use repeatable code and display json data properly

Tags: angular

i am a noob to angular 2 and i really need to make some reuable code.

is there a way to make a shorter reuable version of this

```
answer1 = false;
answer2 = false;
answer3= false;

onClick1(){
   this.answer1 = true; 
   this.answer2 = false; 
   this.answer3 = false; 
 };

 onClick2(){
   this.answer1 = false; 
   this.answer2 = true; 
   this.answer3 = false; 
 };

 onClick3(){
   this.answer1 = false; 
   this.answer2 = false; 
   this.answer3 = true; 
 };
```

aswell as that does anyone know how i am surpossed to be displaying this information as i know this isnt right. i am bringing in this json code

```
[{
        "id": 1,
        "question":"What do you think of the new platform?",
        "Answers":{ 
        "answer1": "It's awesome",
        "answer2": "It's no better than the old version",
        "answer3": "It's confusing!"}



    }];
```

and i can only seem to display it by using *ngIf even though it is only one peice of information?

```
<p (click)="onClick1()" [class.active]="answer1" *ngFor="#question of questions">{{question.Answers.answer1}}</p>
<p (click)="onClick2()"[class.active]="answer2" *ngFor="#question of questions">{{question.Answers.answer2}}</p>
<p (click)="onClick3()"[class.active]="answer3" *ngFor="#question of questions">{{question.Answers.answer3}}</p>
```

anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like that:

```
answers = {
  answer1: false,
  answer2: false,
  answer3: false,
};

onClick(answerNumber) {
  Object.keys(this.answers).forEach((key) => this.answers[key] = false);
  this.answers[answerNumber] = true; 
}
```

and use it this way in the template:

```
<template ngFor #answer [ngForOf]="answers | keyValues">
  <p (click)="onClick(answer.key)" 
        [class.active]="answers[answer.key]"
        *ngFor="#question of questions">
    {{question.Answers[answer.key]}}
  </p>
</template>
```

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/6DenBCOfVnRRVy1rqPmN?p=preview.

The key / value pipe is described in this question:

- [print attributes values from JSON array in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36364556/print-attributes-values-from-json-array-in-angular2/36365117#36365117)

Comment: Thank you very much! you are a angular2 Wizard! I have no idea how that works i'm just glad it does :)

Comment: You're welcome ;-) The central point is to have an object containing the keys for possible answers...