# Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'

Tags: arrays, json, angular, typescript

I am working on angular 2 application, in my current project I am getting the data from my API and It's gives the JSON like below.

```
{
    "makes": null,
    "models": null,
    "trims": null,
    "years": null,
    "assetTypes": {
        "2": "Auto",
        "3": "Motorcycle"
    }
}
```

Next I am converting the JSON data to typescript using json2ts tool from this link http://json2ts.com/

**Typescript.ts**

```
export interface AssetTypes {
    2: string;
    3: string;
}

export interface RootObject {
    makes?: any;
    models?: any;
    trims?: any;
    years?: any;
    assetTypes: AssetTypes;
}
```

Then After I will use below lines of code In my **component.ts**

```
 lookupdetailsassettypeinfo: RootObject;
 this._vehicleInfoService.getLookupDetailsTableAssetTypeInfo()
        .subscribe(lookupdetailsinfo => this.lookupdetailsassettypeinfo = lookupdetailsinfo,
        error => this.error = <any>error);
```

But when I am using the lookupdetailsassettypeinfo in my **component.html** like this below. it always gives the exception like Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

```
<select id="ASSET_TYPE" class="col-md-12 form-control" >
    <option>Select One</option>
    <option *ngFor='let type of lookupdetailsassettypeinfo'>{{type.assetTypes.Customer}}</option>
</select>
```

Can you please tell me how to resolve the above exception.

-Pradeep

Comment: If you change `.subscribe(lookupdetailsinfo => this.lookupdetailsassettypeinfo = lookupdetailsinfo,` to `.subscribe(lookupdetailsinfo => {this.lookupdetailsassettypeinfo = lookupdetailsinfo; console.log(this.lookupdetailsassettypeinfo); }, what does it print?

Comment: `lookupdetailsassettypeinfo: RootObject;` already indicates that it's not supposed to be an array.

Comment: I am trying this line of code  lookupdetailsassettypeinfo: RootObject[] but it doesn't work

Comment: This type is ignored at runtime, this is why I said "indicates". What's relevant is what the `console.log(...)` call prints.

Comment: on the console option, I got the results like this below.

[object Object] {assetTypes: Object {...}, makes: null, models: null, trims: null, years: null}

Comment: Doesn't look like an array ;-)

Comment: I am new to typescript, So can you please tell me how to make my results looks likes an array

Comment: change this  lookupdetailsassettypeinfo: RootObject; to this lookupdetailsassettypeinfo: RootObject[]; and change the map type in service too.

Comment: If they actually aren't arrays it's probably better you use a pipe as shown in the answer I linked to in my answer below.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to convert exact typescript class for this below JSON.

{
  "makes": null,
  "models": null,
  "trims": null,
  "years": null,
  "assetTypes": {
    "2": "Auto",
    "3": "Motorcycle"
  }
}

Comment: Can you please tell me in the above JSON I want to bind only assetTypes values like "Auto" and "MotorCycle" to my dropdown list in view.

Answer (score 0):

`*ngFor` doesn't support iterating over object properties. It only supports arrays.

See also [Access Typescript Object Variables in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36481970/access-typescript-object-variables-in-angular2/36482014#36482014)

Comment: Thanks, I know *ngFor doesn't support iterating over object properties. It only supports arrays. can you please tell me  in my code where I did mistake and how to resolve the above issue