# Angular 2: Create drop-down list with array of dictionaries

Tags: angularjs, json, angular

I'm using options tag in Angular 2 to populate my dropdown list. The dropdown list is populating correctly with `dateTest1.json`, however, when iterating thru the values of a given key in a .json file, then it's having trouble populating the drop down list. What's the correct way in Angular 2 for populating dropdown list with `dateTest.json` example below?

`*.component.html` when retrieving from dateTest.json: `EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'month' of undefined in [dateAttributesList.month in *Component@63:22]`

```
<option *ngFor="#m of dateAttributesList.month" [value]="m">{{m}}</option>
```

dateTest.json:

```
[
    {"month": ["Dec", "Jan", ...]},
    {"day" : ["1","2"...]}
]
```

*.component.html when retrieving from dateTest1.json: correctly populating

```
<option *ngFor="#m of dateAttributesList" [value]="m">{{m}}</option>
```

dateTest1.json:

```
[
    {"month": "Dec"},
    {"month": "Jan"},
    {"month": "Feb"},
    ...
 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the safe navigation operator if the value you bind to is passed by an input or fetched by an async call:

```
<option *ngFor="#m of dateAttributesList?.month" [value]="m.month">{{m}}</option>
```

`[value]` only supports string values. If you have object values use `[ngValue]`

```
<option *ngFor="#m of dateAttributesList" [ngValue]="m.month">{{m}}</option>
```

`[ngValue]` only works with `[ngModel]`

Comment: the dropdown menu isn't populating correctly with dateTest.json, I've edited my question.

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: There is no errors now, but I fail to see any month values in my drop down list

Comment: I can't see from your question what `dateAttributesList.month` returns. Try `{{m.month}}` instead of `{{m}}`

Comment: dateAttributesList.month should return a list of values for the top level key: "month", in the variable dateAttributes.  In example: dateTest.json, it will iterate the values of month, and return ["Dec", "Jan"...]

Comment: How can I iterate thru the values of a given key, instead of iterating thru the key value pairs.

Comment: That are string values. Then you don't need `[ngValue]`. I guess `dateAttributesList?.month` is all you need.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31490713/iterate-over-typescript-dictionary-in-angular-2