# fail reading object type of json

Tags: html, json, typescript, angular, getjson

i have an Object type of json that I cant read...

this is my json:

```
body: {
    "111": {
        "name": "name1",
        "status": 10000
    },
    "222": {
        "name": "name2",
        "status": 20000
    },
    "333": {
        "name": "name3",
        "status": 30000
    }
}
```

and I want to know how to present it in my html?

this is my attempt:

```
<md-content>
    <h1 align="center">{{title}}</h1>
    <h2>list of items:</h2>
    <div class="list-bg"  *ngFor="#item of items | async">
        ID: {{item.name}} <p></p> Number of Items: {{item.status}}
    </div>
</md-content>
```

not only that it dosent work, im trying to figure out how to read each line the object id's(those: `111`, `222`, `333`)

this is my model:

```
  export interface MyModel {
        name: string;
        status: number;
    }
```

this is my component:

```
export class MyCmp implements OnInit {
    retJson: Observable<MyModel[]>

    constructor(private _myService: MyService) {};

    public showData(): void {
        this.retJson = this._myService.getData();
    }
}
```

thanks!

Comment: how are you loading this json?

Comment: @NitzanTomer iv set a mock file to hold my json, and im using http GET to retrieve it, using Observable im subscribing to it in my component. it works with different stracture of json

Comment: Then you need to add that piece of code (which loads the json) to your question

Comment: @NitzanTomer done.

Comment: The code for `this._myService` isn't included so there's no way to know how `getData` is implemented.  In any case, I answered a more general answer. You should include all relevant code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't included how you load your json, so I'll write a more general example:

```
interface MyModel {
    name: string;
    status: number;
}

interface MyResponse {
    body: { [id: string]: MyModel }
}

let response: MyResponse = JSON.parse(RESPONSE_STRING);
Object.keys(response.body).forEach(id => {
    let model = response.body[id];
    console.log(`id: ${ id }, name: ${ model.name }, status: ${ model.status }`);
});
```

What's missing here is the `RESPONSE_STRING`, which I'm not sure how you get.
As for the template, I'm not an angular developer but as far as I understand `ngFor` is used for arrays, and you don't have an array in your json structure.

Answer (score 0):

1. ngFor loop only will work for array. Your body json is key value object, so it wouldn't work.
2. If you want to make it work, it's either:

   - you use an additional pipe to convert key value object to array using pipe, solution discussed here: [Iterate over TypeScript Dictionary in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31490713/iterate-over-typescript-dictionary-in-angular-2), then you can use
     `*ngFor="let item of items | async | mapToIterable"`
   - Or process it in your ts file, instead of 
     `this.retJson = this._myService.getData();`, use `this._myService.getData().subscribe(x => this.retJson = processToArray(x))`