# Angular2 Iterating ngFor JSON-File

Tags: arrays, json, angular, ngfor

I´m fairly new to Angular2, and i want to read out a json file. It´s working, that I get the file from a REST-Client, i can save the file in a local variable in a component. Now I´m trying to read properties (Array) with ngFor, but this isn´t working. 
Here´s the html:

```
<div *ngFor="let categories of tasks.tasks">
    {{categories}} --> Display name of categorie (epg, recs)
    <p *ngFor="let task of categories">{{task.text}}</p>
</div>
```

And the JSON-File:

```
{
    "tasks": {
        "epg": [{
            "text": "\\\\...\\Daten\\Videos\\Aufnahmen"
        }, {
            "text": "C:\\Users\\...\\Desktop"
        }],
        "recs": [{
            "text": "\\\\...\\Daten\\Videos\\Aufnahmen"
        }, {
            "text": "C:\\...\\Junias\\Desktop"
        }]
    }
}
```

Hope someone can help me ;)

Comment: What does 'isnt working' mean? Does it show anything? Does it show nothing?

Comment: The subtree `tasks` is not an array, so you can't loop through it with `ngFor`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31490713/iterate-over-typescript-dictionary-in-angular-2

Comment: Thanks for the comment, i changed the subtree tasks to an Array ;)

But there´s still the question of how can i loop through both arrays...
There stands `[object Object]` instead of "epg" or "recs".
The question is, how can i get the value (name) of the "categorie" ?
And how can i loop through both JSON-Arrays ;)

Answer (score 0):

Consider

```
z={
"tasks": {
    "epg": [{
        "text": "\\\\...\\Daten\\Videos\\Aufnahmen"
    }, {
        "text": "C:\\Users\\...\\Desktop"
    }],
    "recs": [{
        "text": "\\\\...\\Daten\\Videos\\Aufnahmen"
    }, {
        "text": "C:\\...\\Junias\\Desktop"
    }]
}
```

Modify your JSON as

```
  let a=this.z.tasks;
  this.z = Object.keys(a).map(function(k) { return a[k] });
```

Here is a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ayDj6JdQu5n3P8wLUqEP?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you very much!
But this is a problem, because the tasks (epg, recs, ...) could be N tasks (epg, recs, timers, systems, ...).
So I thought about a "double" ngFor...
Do you also have a solution for this? 
Thanks ;)

Comment: This looks quite good. ;)
But there is one more thing, which isn´t possible (i think so...) in this solution:
I want to display the "key" of the the array, so the output should be:

epg
\\\\...\\Daten\\Videos\\Aufnahmen
C:\\Users\\...\\Desktop

recs
\\\\...\\Daten\\Videos\\Aufnahmen
C:\\Users\\...\\Desktop

Do you understand what i mean?
And it does´nt matter, if the json should be edited or the html ;)

Thank you so much!