# Angular2, templates are only partially executed when using ngAfterContentInit or ngAfterViewInit functions

Tags: angular, typescript, lifecycle, domcontentloaded

When trying to access to a DOM of the document, I find that the template is only partially executed. If I use a `setTimeout` I can workaround the problem, but how is the proper way to do it?

```
import { Component, Input, AfterContentInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'tabs',
    templateUrl: './templates/app.html',
    providers: [ AppService ]
})

export class ShowBookmarksComponent implements AfterContentInit {

    private addListeners():void {
        let timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
            let draggables = document.getElementsByClassName('session');
            console.log(draggables);
            console.log(draggables.length);
            for (let i = 0; i < draggables.length; i++) {
                console.log(i+'  '+draggables.length)
            }

            clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        }, 1000);
    }

    ngAfterContentInit() {
        this.appService.getBookmarkLists(this.sessions)
        .then(() => this.appService.getCurrentTabs(this.current_tabs))
        .then(() => this.addListeners());
    }

 }
```

`appService` is providing data that the template will use to display the html. The template:

```
<section class="current_tabs">
    <div class="session" *ngFor="let current_tab of get_keys(current_tabs);">
        <div class="whatever"></div>
    </div>
</section>

<section class="current_bookmarks">
    <div class="session" *ngFor="let session of get_keys(sessions);">
        <div class="whatever"></div>
    </div>
</section>
```

And somehow*, the part corresponding to `sessions` is filled but the part of `current_tabs` is not **yet** filled. Both `this.sessions` and `this.current_tabs` are correctly filled before calling `addListeners`

*seen as well by `console.log(document.documentElement.innerHTML)` executed before the `setTimeout`

```
<section class="current_tabs">
    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": ""
}-->
</section>

<section class="current_bookmarks">
    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "my_session_201 etc etc etc (correctly filled)
```

(when executing it inside the setTimeout, both are correctly filled)

In the code, what I want is to get the `let draggables = document.getElementsByClassName('session');` correctly retrieved, but I am not getting the ones defined within `<section class="current_tabs">` since it is not yet filled

EDIT: more core [Iterate over TypeScript Dictionary in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31490713/iterate-over-typescript-dictionary-in-angular-2)

```
get_keys(obj : any) : Object {
    return Object.keys(obj);
}
```

Comment: please provide your actual code, thanks, so much easier to help you ;)

Comment: I have included code

Comment: `DOMContentLoaded` is fired before Angular gets initialized.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I have changed the title since this is not about the DOMContentLoaded but about how to access to the DOM once is loaded

Comment: What does `get_keys()` look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait until the `current_tabs` are set, then invoke change detection explicitly (`detectChanges()`), then you can add the listeners directly afterwards:

```
constructor(private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef){}

ngOnInit() {
    this.appService.getBookmarkLists(this.sessions)
    .then(() => this.appService.getCurrentTabs(this.current_tabs))
    .then(() => {
      this.cdRef.detectChanges();
      this.addListeners();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AfterViewChecked is called very frequently by angular to update state of the page when new data is available (bindings, ajax requests etc). You should try to put your code in AfterContentInit which is called when all external data is loaded to page.

see https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/AfterContentInit-class.html

Comment: It doesn't work either, but now I see that the responsible is an async part of the code that creates a delay. Anyway, I didn't know of that directive so thanks!

Comment: No, I was wrong, so AfterContentInit doesn't work and it has to be the a DOM loaded issue since a timeout does the trick

Answer (score 0):

Solved in [Angular2, HostListener, how can I target an element? can I target based on class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41700724/angular2-hostlistener-how-can-i-target-an-element-can-i-target-based-on-class/41700814?noredirect=1#comment70598731_41700814) by @GünterZöchbauer. The problem is that between the 2 functions

```
    .then(() => this.appService.getCurrentTabs(this.current_tabs))
    .then(() => this.addListeners());
```

the renderer needs to display the view. So I should call `addListeners` when the view is updated. Done with

```
    .then(() => {
        this.cdr.detectChanges();
        this.addListeners();
     });
```