# Angular2, HostListener, how can I target an element? can I target based on class?

Tags: angular, events, dom, typescript, addeventlistener

In Angular2, how can I target an element within the HostListener decorator?

```
@HostListener('dragstart', ['$event'])
    onDragStart(ev:Event) {
        console.log(ev);
    }

@HostListener('document: dragstart', ['$event'])
    onDragStart(ev:Event) {
        console.log(ev);
    }

@HostListener('myElement: dragstart', ['$event'])
    onDragStart(ev:Event) {
        console.log(ev);
    }

@HostListener('myElement.myClass: dragstart', ['$event'])
    onDragStart(ev:Event) {
        console.log(ev);
    }
```

The two first work. Any other thing I've tried raises an `EXCEPTION: Unsupported event target undefined for event dragstart`

So, can I implement it to a targeted element? How?

Comment: Can you use rxjs to pass observers from parent to child of the related event?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

`@HostListener()` only supports `window`, `document`, and `body` as global event targets, otherwise it only supports the components host element.

Comment: Then if I want to add a listener to a specific element of a template (of a component), I would need to create a new and separated component for it? Otherwise I will have a listener for the entire template, isn't it?

Comment: If the element is inside your component you can use one of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693061/angular-2-typescript-get-hold-of-an-element-in-the-template/35209681#35209681 to get an `ElementRef` of the element and then you can use `ElementRef.nativeElement.addEventListener(...)`, or you can use http://stackoverflow.com/a/41610950/217408. If it's outside of your component then you can use `document.body.querySelector(...).addEventListener(...)`

Comment: The second option doesn't work for me due to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41695838/angular2-templates-are-only-partially-executed-when-using-ngaftercontentinit-or?noredirect=1#comment70589895_41695838 and I am trying to understand now your first link, thanks!

Comment: The first link only works for elements added by Angular. If you have some JavaScript code or jQuery library, that creates the elements it won't work.

Comment: They are elements created in angular, they are in a template inside a component, and I'd like to attach a listener to all of those elements with a specific className. But I find it difficult to achieve (this should be straightforward so I must be missing something basic here)

Comment: Angular doesn't provide support for that approach. There is no Angular2 way of adding event listeners by class. If the elements are added by Angular, then DOMContentLoaded shouldn't be relevant. `ngAfterViewInit()` should do to be sure the elements exist (except they are removed by `*ngIf="falsy"`.

Comment: It doesn't in my case, in ngAfterViewInit() I have part of the template that is still not displayed and I can't access them (so I can't attach listeners there). It's in the link I've pasted above and I don't have yet a clue of what to do

Comment: If you get the data async from `get_keys` there is no lifecycle callback that fits your need. You need to call your code from the callback that you pass to `.subscribe(response => { your code here})`. The DOM will only be created by  `*ngFor` when the data becomes available.

Comment: `get_keys` doesn't look async. I don't know then. You could try to inject `constructor(private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef){}` and call `this.cdRef.detectChanges()` before you query for elements in `ngAfterViewInit()`, to be sure the view was updated.

Comment: Just found, it's because `current_tabs` is async. Sorry, it's to complex, I don't have that much time to investigate.

Comment: Yes it is async but with promises. But you mean that the fact it is async makes it disconnect from the Angular control, even though there're promises in theory taking care of that? But at least now it makes sense ...

Comment: `async` means that the callback passed to `then(...)` or `subscribe(...)` is called eventually, and only when it's called the data is available, and only when the data is available `*ngFor="..."` will render the items.

Comment: Yes, and I see that the problem is that I execute the adding of the listeners once the data is available in the form of a variable, but then it takes some time for *ngFor to take this data and display it in the template. I would need something that says "now the view is updated, now you can add the listeners", which is something like what you suggested before, but it's like killing a mosquito with a bazooka

Comment: You can use the `this.cdRef.detectChanges()` I mentioned above within the callback. When the data is available and `detectChanges()` is called, the DOM is done rendering.

Comment: Could you give me an example of declaring this.cdRef.detectChanges() with the callback? I've been reading but I don't get how it works. Just by adding this line within a function doesn't make the function to be called whenever there's a change

Comment: `this.cdRef.detectChanges()` invokes change detection once. If you just updated a class field in the current method and want the DOM to be updated accordingly before the next code line is executed, you call it and just continue with the other code below this line.

Comment: It HAS worked, but I'm not sure if this is robust. Because I call `this.cdr.detectChanges();` just after the data is filled (via Promise) and before I add the listeners, but here I am trusting that the time that Angular needs to update the template is faster than the call to detectChanges, and I have the feeling that it works by casuality. Shouldn't I check with a setInterval until I find out that the DOM is updated to be sure?

Comment: `detectChanges()` is doing the DOM updates. It's sync, this means when the call returns (and the next line is executed), then Angular is done updating the DOM.

Comment: Ok, great, then it is solved :D Thanks a lot, actually you could post the solution in the other thread. I've posted one saying the solution is here, so feel free to post there an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks a lot again, very appreciated

Comment: @Enthu sorry, long time I took the React road, too disconnected from Angular now ...

Comment: HostListener('document:click') does not work properly; if i expose element as angular element and that component is shadow dom. on click it always returns shadowdom element in event (event.target) rather than actual click element. is there any workaround for this

Answer (score 45):

Since the accepted answer doesn't actually help to solve the problem, here is a solution.

A better way to achieve this is by creating a directive, this way you can add the directive to any element you wish, and the listeners will only trigger for this particular element.

For example:

```
@Directive({
   selector: "[focus-out-directive]"
})
export class FocusOutDirective {
   @Output() onFocusOut: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<false>();

   @HostListener("focusout", ["$event"])
   public onListenerTriggered(event: any): void {
       this.onFocusOut.emit(true);
   }
}
```

Then on your HTML elements you wish to apply this listener to, just add the directive selector, in this case `focus-out-directive`, and then supply the function you wish to trigger on your component.

Example:

`<input type='text' focus-out-directive (onFocusOut)='myFunction($event)'/>`

Comment: Hi. Your answer is a great one. But, does this handle events for childs elements?

Comment: @JoseAnibalRodriguez this particular use case is for single HTML elements. To achieve this you would need to import this directive into the appropriate modules where you want to use it, and then as per the HTML above, add the directive to every element you want the event to fire. For example if you had nested child elements that you wanted the event to fire, you would need to supply the directive for those elements also. You could then either define different functions if you needed to distinguish which element was clicked, or pass another parameter to it e.g. myFunction($event, 'element1')

Comment: Yes, I know how to use a directive, I just wanted to know if this approach should work on childs elements. But I figured out that this only works on the host. So thanks.

Comment: It should be `new EventEmitter<boolean>()` instead of `new EventEmitter<false>()`

Answer (score 10):

Listen on an element:

```js
import { Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) { }

// Get this.myElement with document.getElement... or ElementRef 
ngOnInit() {

  // scroll or any other event
  this.renderer.listen(this.myElement, 'scroll', (event) => {

    // Do something with 'event'
    console.log(this.myElement.scrollTop);

  });

}}
```

Answer (score 7):

I think better way for global listener is @hostliterner but if you want to target some element you can do like this

```
<div (event)="onEvent($e)"></div>
```

in your angular component

```
onEvent($e) { //do something ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

in component template

```
<div (event)="onMouseEnter()">
    <p>United States of America (mouseenter)</p>
</div>

<div (event)="onMouseOut()">
    <p>United States of America (mouseout)</p>
</div>
```

in class component

```
import { Component, OnInit, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-simpleevent',
  templateUrl: './simpleevent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./simpleevent.component.css']
})
export class SimpleeventComponent implements OnInit {
  @HostListener("mouseenter", ["$event"]) onMouseEnter(event: Event) {
    console.log(event.type);
  }

  @HostListener("mouseout", ["$event"]) onMouseOut(event: Event) {
    console.log(event.type);
    console.log(event.target)
  }
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Comment: Hostlistener by default listens to the event type specified, you do not need to add it again on the specific component......

Comment: @mikegross what do you mean?

Comment: It does work with `mouseenter` event but not with `load` event. How can I call a component function when a certain div is loaded?

Answer (score 1):

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';

    @Directive({
          selector: '[checkClick]'
        })

        export class checkClickDirective implements OnInit {

        @Output() public checkClick = new EventEmitter();

        constructor(private _el: ElementRef) { }

        @HostListener('click', ['$event.target']) public onClick(targetElement) {

            const checkClick = this._el.nativeElement.contains(targetElement);

            (checkClick)?this.checkClick.emit(true):this.checkClick.emit(false);
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Googs, the accepted answer does answer the question but doesn't help find a solution.

I built upon alex's answer as I needed a way to use the functionality I already had in my `@HostListener` for retrieving a list of notifications for different screen sizes.

For example, in my app - the notifications page has its own route on mobile but existed in the sidebar on tablet and screen sizes above, so I couldn't use the `@HostListener` there as it would only trigger when I hit the bottom of the whole page and not the sidebar.

Instead I looked up the `<div>` I was interested in and attached what I needed. So the following code:

```
attachListenerToContainer() {
    let elementToListenTo = this.ele ? this.ele : 'window';

    this.renderer.listen(elementToListenTo, 'scroll', (event) => {
      if(!this.reachedBottom) {
        if((getHeight(this.ele) + getScrollTop(this.ele)) >= getOffset(this.ele)) {
          this.reachedBottom = true;
          this.getNextNotificationsPage();
        }
      }
    });

    function getScrollTop(ele) {
      return ele ? ele.scrollTop : window.scrollY;
    }
    function getHeight(ele) {
      return ele ? ele.clientHeight : window.innerHeight;
    }
    function getOffset(ele) {
      return ele ? ele.scrollHeight : document.body.offsetHeight;
    }
  }
```

The `this.ele` is the container div I'm interested in which I look up in the `ngAfterViewInit()` lifecycle hook for tablet and above. If I can't find that element then I use the window instead - effectively emulating the `@HostListener`

Also - here's how I was looking up, in my case, the container element I wanted:

```
this.ele = document.getElementsByClassName('notifications')[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

If `button` is clicked up to `level` deep in directive, then toggle class: `hide`

```
import { Directive, HostBinding, HostListener } from '@angular/core'


@Directive({
    selector: '[Toggle]',
})
export class ToggleDirective {
    @HostBinding('class.hide') isClosed = true

    @HostListener('click', ['$event.target']) toggleDropdown(el: HTMLElement) {
        if (this.isButton(el)) this.isClosed = !this.isClosed
    }

    isButton(el: HTMLElement, level = 3) {
        for (let btn: HTMLElement | undefined | null = el; level > 0; level--) {
            if (btn?.tagName === 'BUTTON') return true
            btn = btn?.parentElement
        }
        return false
    }
    constructor() {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (listening on tab key)

```
@HostListener('document:keydown.tab', ['$event']) onKeydownHandler(event: KeyboardEvent) {

    if ((document as any).getElementById('parentIdOfHtml').contains((event as any).target)) {
      debugger
    }
  }
```

Answer (score -2):

You can also target any element without @hostlistener and can add necessary events by the following way

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';

constructor(private elementRef:ElementRef) {}

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('my-element')
                                .addEventListener('click', this.onClick.bind(this));
}

onClick(event) {
  console.log(event);
}
```