# Using @HostListener only on certain elements (without manual event binding)

Tags: angular, events

I am using `@HostListener` inside a directive that attaches HTML returned by an API call to the DOM.

The desired behavior is that events are only bound to the elements that have been assigned inside the directive, not for the whole document (see [Angular2, HostListener, how can I target an element? can I target based on class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41700724/angular2-hostlistener-how-can-i-target-an-element-can-i-target-based-on-class/44396010#44396010)
).

When an event is fired, I want to check the element's type and class in order to decide what to do:

```
@HostListener('click', ['$event']) onClick(event) {
// check if it is an internal link 
if (event.toElement.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'a' && event.toElement.className.toLowerCase() == "internal_link") {
   console.log("internal link to: " + event.toElement.href);

    // preventDefault (propagation)
    return false;
} else {
    return;
}

}
```

What's not nice about this approach is that I cannot filter the elements **before** the binding (I do not want to access the DOM directly since using the global event targets is likely to conflict with HTML created by Angular itself). Also, use of the native DOM functions is discouraged in the docs: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html#!#respond-to-user-initiated-events I understood from the docs that `@HostListener` is the preferred way to bind events in Angular2 (the directive is responsible for the elements assigned to the DOM and for the events defined on them).

Is there a better way to do what I want to achieve that does not involve accessing the DOM manually?