# Angular 7 - How to find element's attribute value in a component

Tags: angular, angular7

I have a component  and i have the following elements in component's html and need the element's id on clicking it. Example: on clicking

element with id "l1", i should receive l1 inside onclick.

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-xl-6 col-sm-6">
    <ul>
      <li id = "l1">name1</li>
      <li id = "l2">name2</li>
      <li id = "l3">name3</li>
      <li id = "l4">name4</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I am trying to read id of each

element inside onClick event using @Viewchild in the class but no value is coming in console.log();

```
 @ViewChild('li', {read: ViewContainerRef}) showAllData;

 @HostListener("click") onClick(){
      console.log( $(this.showAllData.nativeElement).attr('id'));
 }
```

Comment: Since you want just an eventListener, maybe this answer might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/41610950/8437694

Comment: See this .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41700724/angular2-hostlistener-how-can-i-target-an-element-can-i-target-based-on-class

Comment: Try to avoid using jquery . this.showAllData.nativeElement.getAttribute("id") 
 instead of $(this.showAllData.nativeElement).attr('id')

Comment: you can also `<li id = "l1" (click)="myfunction('l1')">name1</li>` and forget use @HostListener

Comment: Thank you @Eliseo. It works.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this . Following code will log the li tag's id in the console each time user clicks on the li tag. Hope this is what you are looking for.

```
@HostListener("click" , ['$event.target']) onClick(li) {
    console.log(li.id);
}
```