# Angular 2: ngFor with map, use pipe or rx?

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-services

I have a scenario where the server returns object maps rather than arrays. I need to display the data in an *ngFor.

I have read excellent threads on this such as this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31490713/iterate-over-typescript-dictionary-in-angular-2) which seem to favour using a pipe. I have also read that pipes are pure by default and only get called if there is a change to a primitive or reference, but for performance that still concerns me.

Which would be more performant? Using an angular pipe, or converting the data into an array at the rxjs stream level before even sending the data to the template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though your question is mainly opinion based, you better just fix it from the source if you can, instead of using pipes. If the closest to the source you can get is the call to the server, I suggest you change it there using rxjs, with something like this (untested):

```
this.http.get(url)
    .map(response => response.json())
    .map(data => Object.keys(data).map(key => data [key]);
});
```

Comment: If he wants keys and values, consider `Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => ({ [key]: value}))`

Comment: @AluanHaddad that's a nice addition indeed

Comment: Thank you. It does require a polyfill to support older Browsers and NodeJS runtimes. This is part of core-js and you can also find standalone, individually packaged one like this by mozzila https://github.com/es-shims/Object.entries.