# MapToIterable in Angular pipe with TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript2.0, angular-pipe

Trying to implement a pipe in Angular.  After realizing ngFor wouldn't work with maps.  Some research led me to believe that future features were coming to deal with that but in the meantime a mapToIterable pipe was the answer.

I have the following code:

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'mapToIterable'
})
export class MapToIterablePipe implements PipeTransform  {
  transform(map: Map<string, Object>, args: any = []): any {
    const a: any[] = [];
    console.log(map.keys());  // <- works as expected
    for (const k in map) {
      if (map.has(k)) {
        console.log("hello");  // <- never executes
        console.log(k);
        a.push({key: k, val: map.get(k)});
      }
    }
    console.log(a); // <- always empty
    return a;
  }
}

export const MAPTOITERABLE_PROVIDERS = [
  MapToIterablePipe
];
```

map.keys() gives me a list of correct keys, but nothing else works.

Any suggestion on how to diagnose why my loop isn't filling the array correctly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterate over object in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31490713/iterate-over-object-in-angular)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Map` 'keys' are not object keys and cannot be obtained with `Object.keys()` or `in` operator.

Considering that `map.keys()` returns an iterable, it should be

```
for (const key of Array.from(map.keys())) {
  // this check is unneeded
  // if (map.has(k)) {
  ...
}
```

Or in [TypeScript 2.3 with `downlevelIteration` option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generators-and-iteration-for-es5es3),

```
for (const key of map.keys()) { ... }
```

Or just

```
const a: any[] = Array.from(map.entries()).map(([key, val]) => ({ key, val }));
```

Due to how TypeScript implements spread operator, `[...iterable]` won't work the same way as `Array.from(iterable)` in 2.2 and lower.